# Finding similar blob in Git repository

Tags: git

I have a source file imported into my repository from the other remote repository and want to know when the file is commited in the remote repository.

Unfortunately, [a script to find duplicated blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224687/git-find-duplicate-blobs-files-in-this-tree) does not help me because the file was slightly modified when it was imported.

I think this problem can be solved easily if there is a script to find similar blobs. Does anyone know about that?

Answer (score 1):

Blobs (and other git objects) are indexed by a cryptographic checksum. Such functions have the intended property to not map similar inputs to similar outputs. Thus you cannot use blob ids at all for your task. An possible approach would be to extract all blobs from your git repository and compute a fuzzy checksum (e.g. [ssdeep](http://ssdeep.sf.net)) on them. Then you can search for your blob in the fuzzy checksum space (with edit distance in case of ssdeep).