# How can I find the N largest files in a Git repository?

Tags: git

I wanted to find the 10 largest files in my repository. The script I came up with is as follows:

```bash
REP_HOME_DIR=<top level git directory>
max_huge_files=10

cd ${REP_HOME_DIR}
git verify-pack -v ${REP_HOME_DIR}/.git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | \
  grep blob | \
  sort -r -k 3 -n | \
  head -${max_huge_files} | \
  awk '{ system("printf \"%-80s \" `git rev-list --objects --all | grep " $1 " | cut -d\" \" -f2`"); printf "Size:%5d MB Size in pack file:%5d MB\n", $3/1048576,  $4/1048576; }'
cd -
```

Is there a better/more elegant way to do the same?

By "files" I mean the files that have been checked into the repository.

Comment: Is this really for any directory, or is there something specific about git you are trying to figure out? By you pipes, I assume any unix command is ok?

Comment: Do you mean files being tracked or files on disk? They might not correlate in a way you expect.

Comment: Files that have been checked into the repository.

Comment: @Sumit: What version of them? If it's a binary file that's changed, you'll have both copies in the repo.

Comment: You might look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298314/find-files-in-git-repo-over-x-megabytes-that-dont-exist-in-head

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git find fat commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286183/git-find-fat-commit)

Answer (score 141):

This [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) "one-liner" displays the 10 largest blobs in the repository, sorted from smallest to largest. In contrast to the other answers, this *includes **all** files tracked by the repository*, even those not present in any branch tip.

It's *very fast*, easy to copy & paste and only requires standard GNU utilities.

```
git rev-list --objects --all \
| git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' \
| sed -n 's/^blob //p' \
| sort --numeric-sort --key=2 \
| tail -n 10 \
| cut -c 1-12,41- \
| $(command -v gnumfmt || echo numfmt) --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest
```

The first four lines implement the core functionality, the fifth limits the number of results, while the last two lines provide the nice **human-readable output** that looks like this:

```
...
0d99bb931299  530KiB path/to/some-image.jpg
2ba44098e28f   12MiB path/to/hires-image.png
bd1741ddce0d   63MiB path/to/some-video-1080p.mp4
```

For more information, including further filtering use cases and an output format more suitable for script processing, see my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622179/how-to-find-identify-large-files-commits-in-git-history/42544963#42544963) to a similar question.

**macOS users**: Since `numfmt` is not available on macOS, you can either omit the last line and deal with raw byte sizes or `brew install coreutils`.

Comment: you are not kidding, that is fast!

Comment: When I do this it displays files that are not in my branch tip. The top answer above, by contrast, does not.

Comment: @nfernand That is intended. OP says "By 'files' I mean the files that have been checked into the repository.". For me, that includes files that are not in the current branch's tip. If you need something else, go with the top answer above.

Comment: I used @raphinesse answer to identify files that caused `remote: error: File foo is 114.34 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`. The file `foo` was deleted some commits back, but it's blob still existed in the history. To remove it, I had to use BFG Repo Cleaner.

Comment: And to do that, I used `git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | awk '/^blob/ {print substr($0,6)}' | awk '$2 >= 100*1024^2' | sort --numeric-sort --key=2 --reverse | cut --complement --characters=13-40 | numfmt --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest`

Comment: To show more that `tail`'s default 10 lines use, for example `tail --lines=100` in place of `tail`

Comment: This command does not work on the ancient git 1.8.3 available from CentOS 7: `error: option 'batch-check' takes no value`.

Comment: you can omit the `tail` entirely and just paginate :) `git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | sed -n 's/^blob //p' | sort --numeric-sort --key=2 | cut -c 1-12,41- | $(command -v gnumfmt || echo numfmt) --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest | less +G`

Answer (score 101):

I found another way to do it:

> ```
> git ls-tree -r -t -l --full-name HEAD | sort -n -k 4 | tail -n 10
> ```

Quoted from: [SO: git find fat commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1290046)

Comment: Great answer - I'd change it a bit to `git ls-tree -r -l --abbrev --full-name HEAD | sort -n -r -k 4 | head -n 10`: you do not need `-t` as you are not interested in tree listings (which give no size), `--abbrev` makes the hash more readable, and `head` instead of `tail` gives the list in descending size order

Comment: Doesn't work for files that aren't checked out, or for files that existed some time in the past but were deleted but are still taking up space in a blob somewhere. See raphinesse's answer for a better solution.

Comment: This answer _does_ work for files that aren't checked out - it processes the files in the given commit (`HEAD` in the example) as they appear in that commit, regardless of whether the commit is currently checked out.

Comment: This absolutely does not work for me; the @raphinesse answer is the one. This listed a 167K file as the largest while raphinesse listed a 75M file... and did it with human-readable values.

Answer (score 34):

Use

```
git ls-files | xargs ls -l | sort -nrk5 | head -n 10
```

- `git ls-files`: List all the files in the repo
- `xargs ls -l`: perform `ls -l` on all the files returned in `git ls-files`
- `sort -nrk5`: Numerically reverse sort the lines based on 5th column
- `head -n 10`: Print the top 10 lines

Comment: This is based on files in my current checkout version. If a file of 10MB was committed and then it was overwritten by another version of 1KB, this command won't list that file.

Comment: This answer fails when you have spaces in filenames/folders (although you do get **some** output). This minor change fixes that problem: `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 ls -l | sort -nrk5 | head -n 10`

Comment: I would use a more simplified form: `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 ls -l -h -S -r`. This should get you a list of all files within the repo ordered from smallest to largest with human readable sizes. If you want to truncate the list, you can use `head` or `tail` to help. My 5 cents worth...

Comment: Doesn't work for files that aren't checked out, or for files that existed some time in the past but were deleted but are still taking up space in a blob somewhere. See raphinesse's answer for a better solution.

Comment: Had to us this on my mac: `git ls-files | xargs -0 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 du -h | sort -rh`

Comment: Note, `ls` has an `S` option that sorts by file size already! So you can use `git ls-files | xargs ls -lhS |head -n 10` and have a nice, human-readable output!

Answer (score 11):

I cannot comment. [ypid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456550/how-can-i-find-the-n-largest-files-in-a-git-repository/28783843#28783843) modified for [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell):

```
git ls-tree -r -l --abbrev --full-name HEAD | Sort-Object {[int]($_ -split "\s+")[3]} | Select-Object -last 10
```

A modified version of [raphinesse's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456550/how-can-i-find-the-n-largest-files-in-a-git-repository/46085465#46085465)(ish):

```
git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | Where-Object {$_ -like "blob*"} | Sort-Object {[int]($_ -split "\s+")[2]} | Select-Object -last 10
```

Comment: Doesn't work for files that aren't checked out, or for files that existed some time in the past but were deleted but are still taking up space in a blob somewhere. See raphinesse's answer for a better solution.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is FINALLY an answer that works out of the box on Windows.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me on Windows without the PowerShell complaining

Answer (score 6):

An improvement to raphinesse's answer, sort by size with largest first:

```
git rev-list --objects --all \
| git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' \
| awk '/^blob/ {print substr($0,6)}' \
| sort --numeric-sort --key=2 --reverse \
| head \
| cut --complement --characters=13-40 \
| numfmt --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest
```

Comment: I would hardly call that an improvement. It's more a matter of preference. Plus, if someone just wanted to reverse the line order, they could simply pipe the output of my original script through `tac`.

Comment: @raphinesse For me, this does not simply sort raphinesse's answer in a different order. It also lists a different set of files (in particular, it lists a large file that raphinesse's answer does not list). Is this intended?

Comment: It is not intended; I really just changed the sort order to largest to smallest. Try running just the first 4 lines (to the end of the sort command) of each command and see if there's a difference between the outputs.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, I started with [AdamF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456550/how-can-i-find-the-n-largest-files-in-a-git-repository/57793716#57793716) (thanks!) and modified it to handle files with spaces in the path, and also to output objects instead of strings:

```
git rev-list --objects --all |
 git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype)|%(objectname)|%(objectsize)|%(rest)' |
 Where-Object {$_ -like "blob*"} |
 % { $tokens = $_ -split "\|"; [pscustomobject]@{ Hash = $tokens[1]; Size = [int]($tokens[2]); Name = $tokens[3] } } |
 Sort-Object -Property Size -Descending |
 Select-Object -First 50
```

Even better, if you want to output the file sizes with nice file size units, you can add the [DisplayInBytes function from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40887001/892770) to your environment, and then pipe the above to:

```
Format-Table Hash, Name, @{Name="Size";Expression={ DisplayInBytes($_.Size) }}
```

This gives you output like:

```
Hash                                     Name                       Size
----                                     ----                       ----
f51371aa843279a1efe45ff14f3dc3ec5f6b2322 types/react-snackbar       95.8 MB
84f3d727f6b8f99ab4698da51f9e507ae4cd8879 .ntvs_analysis.dat         94.5 MB
17d734397dcd35fdbd715d29ef35860ecade88cd fhir/fhir-tests.ts         11.5 KB
4c6a027cdbce093fd6ae15e65576cc8d81cec46c fhir/fhir-tests.ts         11.4 KB
```

Lastly, if you'd like to get all the largest file **types**, you can do so with:

```
git rev-list --objects --all |
 git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype)|%(objectname)|%(objectsize)|%(rest)' |
 Where-Object {$_ -like "blob*"} |
 % { $tokens = $_ -split "\|"; [pscustomobject]@{ Size = [int]($tokens[2]); Extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($tokens[3]) } } |
 Group-Object -Property Extension |
 % { [pscustomobject]@{ Name = $_.Name; Size = ($_.Group | Measure-Object Size -Sum).Sum } } |
 Sort-Object -Property Size -Descending |
 select -First 20 -Property Name, @{Name="Size";Expression={ DisplayInBytes($_.Size) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `du` - Example: `du -ah objects | sort -n -r | head -n 10` . du to get the size of the objects, `sort` them and then picking the top 10 using `head`.

Comment: only tells the object not the name of the file. Will require tricks to ignore the pack files as well.

Comment: Doesn't work for files that aren't checked out, or for files that existed some time in the past but were deleted but are still taking up space in a blob somewhere. See raphinesse's answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my two cents on how to do this for the whole repository history (useful before [BFGing](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) out the large blobs committed by accident):

```
git rev-list --all | while read rev ; do git ls-tree -rl --full-name $rev ; done | sort -k4 -nr | uniq
```

Example output (from the `dte` repository from GitHub) reveals that there's one screenshot in history that may probably be removed to keep the whole repository a bit smaller:

```
100644 blob 3147cb8d0780442f70765a005f1a114442f24e9b   67942    Documentation/screenshot.png
100644 blob 36ea7701a6d58185800e22c39cac78d979f4375a   62575    Documentation/screenshot.png
100644 blob c0cd355f06a093cd762339b76f0e726edf22fca1   49046    src/command.c
100644 blob 76d20c2e4a80cd3f417d15c130ee6968e99d6d7f   48601    src/command.c
100644 blob c476fbf2fda71ebd4b337e62fb76922d18aeb1f3   48588    src/command.c
100644 blob 24465d1fab54e48817780338f8206baf47e98091   48451    src/command.c
100644 blob 74494b6020b2eff223dfaeed39bbfca414f2b359   48429    src/command.c
100644 blob fb8f13abe39ca8ff0e98aa65f95c336c9253b487   47838    src/command.c
100644 blob c2ce190eb428c3aeb12d40cf902af2a433324dee   47835    src/command.c
...
```

...but this precise repository is okay; no blobs of extreme size were found.

How to find the commits that work with the objects (adding for my own reference, haha):

```
git log --all --find-object=3147cb8d07
```

Answer (score 0):

For completion, here's the method I found:

```
ls -lSh `git ls-files` | head
```

The optional `-h` prints the size in human-readable format.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `find` to find files larger than a given threshold, then pass them to `git ls-files` to exclude untracked files (e.g. build output):

```
find * -type f -size +100M -print0 | xargs -0 git ls-files
```

Adjust 100M (100 megabytes) as needed until you get results.

Minor caveat: this won't search top-level "hidden" files and folders (i.e. those whose names start with `.`).  This is because I used `find *` instead of just `find` to avoid searching the `.git` database.

I was having trouble getting the `sort -n` solutions to work (on Windows under Git Bash).  I'm guessing it's due to indentation differences when xargs batches arguments, which `xargs -0` seems to do automatically to work around Windows' command-line length limit of 32767.

Comment: Doesn't work for files that aren't checked out, or for files that existed some time in the past but were deleted but are still taking up space in a blob somewhere. See raphinesse's answer for a better solution.