# How do we get the size of the file in KB using powershell scripting?

Tags: powershell

I have tried `$filesize=(($fileXP).length/1KB)`
 but this does not retrieve the correct answer.
As for my understanding, it is just dividing the number of characters in files with KB and giving the answer which is wrong.

There has to be some function or attribute to define the size directly and display as we want in KB or MB or GB as required.

Comment: I suspect I can find a dupe target for this but we cannot explain your problem until I see how you made `$fileXP`

Comment: *"this does not retrive the correct answer"* -- So... What is `$fileXP`? What is `($fileXP).length`? And what is `(($fileXP).length/1KB)`? Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616806/powershell-display-file-size-as-kb-mb-or-gb

Comment: If `$fileXP` is a `FileInfo` object as returned by `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem`, then the `Length` property is the *number of bytes* not (necessarily) "number of characters" in the file

Comment: Hi All,
$filexp is the variable has .xml file stored
$filesize is the variable that holds the output of the size of the that .xml file
So it is the simple operartion to pcalcute the size of the file and store it in a variable

Answer (score 13):

To get the file sizes in KB:

```
Get-ChildItem | % {[int]($_.length / 1kb)}
```

Or to round up to the nearest KB:

```
Get-ChildItem | % {[math]::ceiling($_.length / 1kb)}
```

To get the number characters:

```
Get-ChildItem | % {(Get-Content $_.FullName).length}
```

Compare the output and you will see that the length of `Get-Childitem` is in KB.

Comment: But Dave,
i have the file stored in $file and now if i have to calculate the size directly and then print it out.
So this cant be the solution, Can you advise the solution for that

Comment: Can you show the code that assigns to `$file`? Unless I know what it contains I can't help.

Comment: $fileXP = "XXSDSKILLSXP_data.xml"
$Directory = "C:\Interfaces\"
if (Test-Path $Directory$fileXP)
$filesize=($fileXP.length/1KB)

Here i  have a stored file in the path i have defines the path and file in variables. i am using as above to find the size

Comment: So $fileXP does contain a file, just a string that happens to be a file name. The length for your variable would be just the number of chars in the string.   To get a file object you will have to pass you string to something that returns a file object, something like: `(Get-ChildItem $fileXP).length`.

Comment: Yes,  i have used this (Get-ChildItem $fileXP).length
But i dont think i can store the output of the above into another String Variable and then Use that variable for mailing in HTML.

Comment: Why do think this can't be done? How about `$x = (Get-ChildItem $fileXP).length.ToString()` or even `$x = [string]((Get-ChildItem $fileXP).length)`.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I wasnt able ro produce teh correct answer because it want converted to String.
Thanks for you Help.

Answer (score 3):

First:

```
Get-Item -Path 'C:\Windows\notepad.exe' | Select -Property Name, Length | Foreach {
    #if($_.('Name').Trim() -eq "notepad.exe") {
        $FileSize = $_.Length
    #}
};
```

Wow ... directly and display as we want in KB, or MB or GB? I have not seen COM functions that provide such in-depth information. This is the limit I saw, run this:

```
<#The word 'Properties'/'Сво&йства'(ru) should be here, for the English version of#> 
<#Windows with "&" somewere. What is shown when the right mouse button#> 
<#to file/folder is pressed#>
$itemName = 'Сво&йства';
$fullPath='C:\Windows';
$o = new-object -com Shell.Application;
$folder = $o.NameSpace((Split-Path -Path $fullPath));
$file = $folder.ParseName((Split-Path -Leaf $fullPath));
$file.Verbs() | foreach ({
    if($_.Name -eq $itemName){$_.DoIt()}
});
```

Due to the fact that Powershell has the same sources as WMIC, where data is sent in bytes, I think that the solution may be to crack some dll file, well ... or completely repeat the logic of microsoft in obtaining information of this type?

I would really like it if I was wrong. This would simplify some of my past executable code decisions.

Comment: this does not answer the Question.

Comment: #Wow ... directly and display as we want in KB, or MB or GB? I have not seen COM functions that provide such in-depth information. This is the limit I saw, run this:
$itemName = 'Сво&йства';<#The word 'Properties' should be here, for the English version of Windows with "&" somewere. What is shown when the right mouse button is pressed#> $fullPath='C:\Windows'; $o = new-object -com Shell.Application; $folder = $o.NameSpace((Split-Path -Path $fullPath)); $file = $folder.ParseName((Split-Path -Leaf $fullPath)); $file.Verbs() | foreach ({ if($_.Name -eq $itemName){$_.DoIt()} });

Answer (score 1):

```
CLS

$filenames=Get-Content "C:\temp\files\files-to-watch-size.txt" **#Reading the names of the files to test the existance and size of the file, name of fles with full path in each line e.g. C:\test.txt**
foreach ($filename in $filenames) 
{

if (Test-Path $filename) { (Get-Item $filename).length -gt 0kb **#Returns TRUE if size is greater than zero KB**
$size=(Get-Item $filename).length/1024  **#Getting the File size in KB**
Write-Host "$filename is $size KB" } **# display the name of the file and its size in KB**
}
```

Comment: The question is how to get a file's size in kilobytes.  This is for some reason iterating a list of files, for each one outputting a boolean indicating if it has data or not and writing to the host the size in bytes.  Where is the size in kilobytes?  [Dave Sexton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38058434/150605) from three years ago already addresses this, anyways.

Comment: Just divide the byte value by 1024 to get KB e.g. "$size=(Get-Item $filename).length/1024" you can convert the byte value to KB, MB, GB or whatever just by dividing by appropriate number!

Comment: I've found this to be slightly speedier than get-item, though that difference is only a few Milliseconds.
    ([System.IO.FileInfo] $path).length / 1kb

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the bytes (* to get all files... could have used e.g. *.mp3):

```
 Get-ChildItem * | Measure-Object -Property Length -sum
```

This will give you the size in MB:

```
 "{0} MB" -f ((Get-ChildItem * -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -S -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB)
```

etc.