# powershell filesize total from a directory listing

Tags: file, powershell, input, directory, filesize

I have created a directory list of files like this:

```
JPGS.LST:
"L:\_Testing\2016-05-20 20.22.53.jpg"
"L:\_Testing\2016-05-20 20.23.07.jpg"
"L:\_Testing\2016-05-20 20.23.12.jpg"
"L:\_Testing\2016-05-20 20.59.31.jpg"
"L:\_Testing\2016-05-20 21.19.25.jpg"
"L:\_Testing\2016-05-20 21.19.28.jpg"
"L:\_Testing\2016-05-20 21.49.09.jpg"
"L:\_Testing\2016-05-20 21.49.12.jpg"
```

From this list I want to get a total of all the file sizes - from the list.

I'm using this list to reduce these images.  I want to run the script again to see total size of the same files after the reduction, so I have a before and after comparison.  Other examples I see use a powershell directory listing...I need to be able to use the input file to determine total size of files in the directory listing.

I've tried:

```
$Files=Get-Content $Listfile
$totalSize = ($Files | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum Length).Sum
```

but that's not producing expected results.  I'd like it to resolve to something like

`$TotalSize=12.5 MB`

Obi Wan....you're my only hope!

Comment: `$Files` returns strings, you are measuring string length. You'll need a ForEach to iterate and Get-Item to obtain the Length of each file, like my answer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to iterate the files contained in JPGS.LST:

```
$TotalSize = 0
ForEach ($File in Get-Content '.\JPGS.LST'){
    If (Test-Path $File.Trim('"')){$TotalSize+=(GI $File.Trim('"')).Length}else{"$File not found"}
}
"`$TotalSize={0:N2} MB" -f ($TotalSize/1MB)
```

Comment: This is close, but it's saying all the files "not found", even though they exist.

Comment: The double quotes in your file have to be removed. Changed above - try again

Comment: I had just determined that the " was the problem, and came here and see you identified that and provided the solution.  How do you do that so easily?!?!  Brilliant!  Thank you Obi Wan!  :-)

Comment: I sure wish these comment were as easy to edit as the post.  Can't seem to format the working code block readably:    `$ListFile=$args[0]
$TotalSize = 0
ForEach ($File in Get-Content $ListFile){
    If (Test-Path $File.Trim('"')){$TotalSize+=(GI $File.Trim('"')).Length}else{"$File not found"}
}
"`$TotalSize={0:N2} MB" -f ($TotalSize/1MB)`

Answer (score 2):

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -File
$sum=($files | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum).sum
```

If you want a desired output with sum (MB, GB ..etc), check [PowerShell display files size as KB, MB, or GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616806/powershell-display-files-size-as-kb-mb-or-gb/24617034#24617034) discussion with cool techniques.

Comment: This doesn't seem correct.  isn't "Get-Childitem $path -Recurse" doing it's own directory listing?  I need it to iterate a supplied file listing.
    Tried this:
    `$ListFile="JPGSDIR.lst"

$sum=($ListFiles | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum).sum
write-Host $Sum
`
   I clearly don't understand the syntax...that's why I'm here!

Comment: Right, you needed to import a file (which has list of file paths)-- I missed that. What I have provided is for listing files from a particular path. LotPings' solution works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
ls -recurse | % { [long]($_.Length) } | Measure-Object -sum | % { $_.Sum }
```

Comment: OK...I kinda get what you're doing, but trying to interpret. Though I'm getting a number, it's not the correct number.  `$totalsize = $Files | % { [int]($_.Length) } | Measure-Object -sum | % { $_.Sum }
write-Host $TotalSize1`

Comment: I have subdirectories added to the script (recurse).