# How to set two variables for the same column?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Suppose I have the following statement

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "UPDATE [$Table]
SET [size] = '$newSize.Size $newSize.Unit'
WHERE [cname] = '$cube'" -ConnectionString $CS
```

This doesn't work and throws the following error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : String or binary data would be truncated. The
> statement has been terminated.

In the table, I see this in the field:

> @{Size=919.8; Unit=MB}.Size

This is because I'm setting two variables in one statement, but what is the proper syntax for that?

I am trying to store the following value: 919.8 MB

I tried this: `'$estimatedSize.Size','$estimatedSize.Unit'`

But it doesn't work either

More info related to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57531267/8397835

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right syntax:

```
SET [size] = '$($newSize.Size) $($newSize.Unit)'
```