# How to get output in GB instead of B

Tags: powershell

I found a script to check the available space on a remote computer. However I can't find how I can get the output in GB instead of B.
I don't know a lot about Powershell. Can somebody help me adjusting this code so I can see the available free disk space on a remote computer

```
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName STR3598C -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object Size,FreeSpace 

$disk.Size
$disk.FreeSpace
```

Comment: If you actually looking for a more human readable format, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57530347/1701026

Answer (score 4):

A possible way to achieve this could be to use the following:

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName STR3598C -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
```

Expected output:

```
DeviceId MediaType   Size FreeSpace
-------- ---------   ---- ---------
C:              12 215.52     111.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to store the results in a variable (like with your code example) and format that for output to screen and/or save it in a CSV file:

```
$computer = 'STR3598C'
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computer -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | 
        Select-Object @{Name = 'Computer'; Expression = {$_.PSComputerName}},
                      DeviceID, VolumeName,
                      @{Name = 'Size'; Expression = {'{0:N2}' -f ($_.Size / 1GB)}},
                      @{Name = 'FreeSpace'; Expression = {'{0:N2} GB' -f ($_.FreeSpace / 1GB)}}

# output on screen
$disk | Format-Table -AutoSize

# or save the output as CVS
$disk | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\disksize.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen

> ```
> Computer DeviceID VolumeName Size      FreeSpace
> -------- -------- ---------- ----      ---------
> STR3598C C:       Systeem    232,79 GB 89,33 GB
> ```