# How to make variable value in to GB or TB in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps pipeline, I have written a PowerShell script in variables for storage are defined, those variables will be given while running the pipeline. I need to take those variable show as GB.

1. Here in below example x,y,z values given in pipeline like 256, 512, 1024. Those values should be considered as 256GB, 512GB, 1024GB in my PowerShell script
2. In the same code I need to give 3 TB value to variable `$Maxsize`. Did I mentioned in correct format or is there any other format?

PowerShell script:

```
$sum = $x+$y+$z 

$Maxsize = 3 / 1TB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what direction you want to go (or at least there is some confusion).

### To convert *from* GB/TB:

**Directly using the interpreter:**

```
$Maxsize = 3TB
$Maxsize
```

Yields (the maximal size in bytes):

```
3298534883328
```

<sub>(*note:* [KB: 1024 vs 1000](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/kb-1024-vs-1000/))</sub>

**From a string:**

```
$x = '256GB'
$y = '512GB'
$z = '1024GB'

$Total = 0 + $x + $y +z
```

Note that the implicit [type casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) will follow the type of the first operand (`0`) and add all following variables as numbers (instead of strings).

**From a integer (that represents `GB` units):**

```
$x = 256
$y = 512
$z = 1024

$Total = 0 + "$($x + $y + $z)GB"
```

In this example the total of `$x + $y + $z` will be converted to a string and suffixed with `GB` and than implicitly converted to a number by adding it to a numeric value (`0`).

### To convert *to* GB/TB:

For this you might use the `Format-ByteSize` function or one of the other answers to the question [How to convert value to KB, MB, or GB depending on digit placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57535324/1701026):

```
Format-ByteSize $Total
```

Yields:

```
1.75 TB
```