# How to convert the output value stored in variable which is in bytes) into KB MB GB dynamically via powershell script

Tags: powershell

```
$nametask = Get-NetBackupJob -JobId "96953"

$number = $nametask.kbytes

if ($number -lt 1KB) {
    return "$number B"
} elseif ($number -lt 1MB) {
    $number = $number / 1KB
    $number = "{0:N2}" -f $number
    return "$number KB"
} elseif ($number -lt 1GB) {
    $number = $number / 1MB
    $number = "{0:N2}" -f $number
    return "$number MB"
} elseif ($number -lt 1TB) {
    $number = $number / 1GB
    $number = "{0:N2}" -f $number
    return "$number GB"
} elseif ($number -lt 1PB) {
    $number = $number / 1TB
    $number = "{0:N2}" -f $number
    return "$number TB"
} else {
    $number = $number / 1PB
    $number = "{0:N2}" -f $number
   return "$number PB"`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: I don't get any output from d above code sniplet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert value to KB, MB, or GB depending on digit placeholders?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57535324/1701026): **`Format-ByteSize 79410065774139`**  **`72.2 TB`**

Answer (score 3):

I use this function

```
Function Get-FriendlySize {
    Param($bytes)
    switch($bytes){
        {$_ -gt 1TB}{"{0:N2} TB" -f ($_ / 1TB);break}
        {$_ -gt 1GB}{"{0:N2} GB" -f ($_ / 1GB);break}
        {$_ -gt 1MB}{"{0:N2} MB" -f ($_ / 1MB);break}
        {$_ -gt 1KB}{"{0:N2} KB" -f ($_ / 1KB);break}
        default {"{0:N2} Bytes" -f $_}
    }
}
```

Then just call the function passing the number you'd like to convert

```
Get-FriendlySize 2255846589
2.10 GB

Get-FriendlySize 79410065774139
72.22 TB
```

Edit:

The number you showed in your comment is really, really big. For a number that large you can use `[bigint]`. Here is an updated function that will handle that large of a number.

```
Function Get-FriendlySize {
    Param([bigint]$bytes)
    switch($bytes){
        {$_ -gt 1PB}{"{0:N2} PB" -f ($_ / 1PB);break}
        {$_ -gt 1TB}{"{0:N2} TB" -f ($_ / 1TB);break}
        {$_ -gt 1GB}{"{0:N2} GB" -f ($_ / 1GB);break}
        {$_ -gt 1MB}{"{0:N2} MB" -f ($_ / 1MB);break}
        {$_ -gt 1KB}{"{0:N2} KB" -f ($_ / 1KB);break}
        default {"{0:N2} Bytes" -f $_}
    }
}

Get-FriendlySize 9544198954419895489544198954419895441989544198954419895441989544198954
8,476,951,544,640,250,324,628,133,400,343,462,843,526,386,001,563,877,376.00 PB
```

Comment: I get this error 

95441989544198954
89544198954419895441989544198954419895441989544198954" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or 
too small for an Int32."
At C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\scripts\try.ps1:8 char:1
+ $numberInGigabytes = $numberInBytes / 1GB
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
 

PS C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\scripts>

Comment: $nametask = Get-NetBackupJob -JobId "96953"
$number = $nametask.kbytes
$bytes= $number * 1024
Function Get-FriendlySize {
    Param($bytes)
    switch($bytes){
        {$inbytes -gt 1TB}{"{0:N2} GB" -f ($inbytes / 1TB);break}
        {$inbytes -gt 1GB}{"{0:N2} GB" -f ($inbytes / 1GB);break}
        {$inbytes -gt 1MB}{"{0:N2} MB" -f ($inbytes / 1MB);break}
        {$inbytes -gt 1KB}{"{0:N2} KB" -f ($inbytes / 1KB);break}
        default {"{0:N2} Bytes" -f $inbytes}
    }
}

Comment: these are my commands which get the ouput in the variable number which has data in KB

$nametask = Get-NetBackupJob -JobId "96953"
$number = $nametask.kbytes

Comment: You may use `[INT64]$bytes` to be able to work with bigger numbers

Comment: Please take a look at the edit. If it answers your question please don't forget to mark it as such.

Comment: `$nametask = Get-NetBackupJob -JobId "96953"

$number = $nametask.kbytes
$bytes= $number * 1024
Function Get-FriendlySize {
    Param([bigint]$bytes)
    switch($bytes){
        {$new -gt 1PB}{"{0:N2} PB" -f ($new / 1PB);break}
        {$new -gt 1TB}{"{0:N2} TB" -f ($new / 1TB);break}
        {$new -gt 1GB}{"{0:N2} GB" -f ($new / 1GB);break}
        {$new -gt 1MB}{"{0:N2} MB" -f ($new / 1MB);break}
        {$new -gt 1KB}{"{0:N2} KB" -f ($new / 1KB);break}
        default {"{0:N2} Bytes" -f $new}
    }
}`

I dont get any result is my syntax right?

Comment: You changed the function, why? This has broken the function as `$new` is unknown.  All you have to do is call `Get-FriendlySize $number` and don't change the function.

Answer (score 1):

to convert a number to KB, MB, GB, etc you have to get the base in Bytes. so if the base is KB you

```
$numberInBytes = $number * 1024
```

then you can divide it by the desired unit like

```
$numberInKilobytes = $numberInBytes / 1KB
$numberInMegabytes = $numberInBytes / 1MB
$numberInGigabytes = $numberInBytes / 1GB
```

adding it to your script like

```
$nametask = Get-NetBackupJob -JobId "96953"

$number = $nametask.kbytes * 1024

if ($number -lt 1KB) {
    return "$number B"
} elseif ($number -lt 1MB) {
    $number = $number / 1KB
    $number = "{0:N2}" -f $number
    return "$number KB"
} elseif ($number -lt 1GB) {
    $number = $number / 1MB
    $number = "{0:N2}" -f $number
    return "$number MB"
} elseif ($number -lt 1TB) {
    $number = $number / 1GB
    $number = "{0:N2}" -f $number
    return "$number GB"
} elseif ($number -lt 1PB) {
    $number = $number / 1TB
    $number = "{0:N2}" -f $number
    return "$number TB"
} else {
    $number = $number / 1PB
    $number = "{0:N2}" -f $number
   return "$number PB"`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: I get this error 

95441989544198954
89544198954419895441989544198954419895441989544198954" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or 
too small for an Int32."
At C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\scripts\try.ps1:8 char:1
+ $numberInGigabytes = $numberInBytes / 1GB
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
 

PS C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\scripts>