# How can we use a command to get exact size of files or folders in CMD?

Tags: windows, file, cmd, filesize

I know nothing about **bat file or cmd file**. I asked chatGPT to pull me someting that I can use as command as such:

> fsize <filename[s]>

where `fsize` takes *filename[s]* and calculate size in human readable format. `fsize.cmd`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%F in (%*) do (
    set "filename=%%F"

    REM Check if the file or folder exists
    if not exist "!filename!" (
        echo !filename! does not exist
    ) else (
        REM Determine if it's a file or folder
        for /f %%A in ('powershell -command "& { if (Test-Path '!filename!' -PathType Leaf) { 'file' } else { 'folder' } }"') do set "type=%%A"

        if /i !type! equ file (
            for /f %%a in ('powershell -command "& {(Get-Item \"!filename!\").length}"') do set "size=%%a"
            if defined size (
                powershell -command "& { $size = !size!; if ($size -lt 1KB) { echo '!filename! = '($size) bytes } elseif ($size -lt 1MB) { echo '!filename! = '($size / 1KB) KB } elseif ($size -lt 1GB) { echo '!filename! = '($size / 1MB) MB } else { Write-Output '!filename! = '($size / 1GB) GB } }"
            )
        ) else if /i !type! equ folder (
            echo !filename! is a folder
        )
    )
)
```

I test it and it is working quite fine. Well I wanna solve couple of issues of this `fsize.cmd` which are:
Before addressing issue I would like to show results of `dir /b` command :

```
file.txt
fsize.cmd
hell
```

where **hell** is folder
**Issue 1**: when I asked `fsize` to render size of **file.txt** as: `fsize file.txt` results:

```
file.txt = 
1.44921875
KB
```

The results are in 3 lines which is untidy. I expect the results to be in one line:
`file.txt = 1.44921875 KB` 
**Issue 2**: if i do `fsize hell` it results:
`hell is a folder`
but when i do `fsize *`

```
file.txt = 
1.44921875
KB
fsize.cmd = 
1013 
bytes
```

It does not echo `hell is a folder` why?

Solution I want:

1. Solve Issue 1
2. I will appreciate anyone helping me modify the `fsize.cmd` in such a way that:
   `fsize <filename[s]|foldername[s]>`
   should render size of provided file/folders in readable format. Saying readable format I mean if size goes 1024B it should convert into KB and as such....
3. `fsize *`      should enounter folders too.

I get that cmd file with the help of chatGPT. This is acknowledgeable anyone saying ask GPT but it is only testing my patience and hence I can not work on these at my own I am posting this.

Comment: at the very least, `Test-Path '!filename!' -PathType Leaf` should return `false` if the provided path is a folder. try `echo !type!`  after than file/folder check. tbh, given how chatgpt throws powershell in cmd it might be better to just ask for a powershell script altogether - it may spew something better.

Comment: for the *"should render size in readable format"* may involve ifs, division, and rounding, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616806/powershell-display-files-size-as-kb-mb-or-gb).

Comment: @BagusTesa, I did ask for ps script. Well it is disabled in this system(I don't know why/how and for now that is not my point of concern)so there may be alternate way using cmd file. But as I said powershell is only testing my patience.  I don't know what `test-path` does but based on results it seems returning false. The result of `echo !type!` is **file** on command : `fsize *` for each files inside dir. Can you suggest me more ways to solve the issue or modify the file according to my need (i am not being sophisticated, the fact is I don't know how to work with these fbat or cmd files)

Comment: my apology, * powershell is only testing my patience* , its **chatGPT** not powershell.

Comment: "It does not echo hell is a folder why?" Read the documentation for `FOR`: "FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]. (set)      Specifies a set of one or more **files**.  Wildcards may be used." Wildcards in the set filter to files only.

Comment: Directories, _(what you are calling folders)_, do not have a size. What you appear to be looking for, in such cases, would be the combined size of each file located within a directory structure.

Comment: The exact method and format you are using to populate the `<filename[s]>` argument(s) could be crucial to any possible solution. If you could [Edit] your question to include that information, it may prompt more responses or potential solutions.

Comment: @Compo, I thought I was clear, I am sorry for that if I seems quite unclear which is partially true as I review it myself. As far as I understand, saying *The exact method and format you are using to populate the <filename[s]>* I guess you are suggesting me to provide overview on how to get size of `<filename[s]>` (of any type) I am trying to implement . If it is as I said with no knowledge on `.cmd` files I was hoping **chatGPT** could help me & when I found it is not enough Im hoping someone could possibly edit or help edit the file I posted to get the job done without going deeper into it..

Comment: You are passing one or more arguments to the batch file, _(which you are accessing via `%*` in your code)_. How are the argument strings being created, what method are you using to pass them to the script, and what do they look like, (please give examples).?

Comment: @Compo, I have posted how `fsize.cmd` looks like and I am using it on command line which means it is getting input via `stdin`. *args* can be name of any file or folder/directory which may or maynot exist. It should be the job of bat file to check if it exists and calculate the size in readable form ... Talking about implementation as I already said, I know nothing on scripting so I had asked **chatGPT** and when it is not fully satisfactory I am wishing someone to help... to achieve the outcome I mentioned.

Comment: That still does not help me! Are you manually typing the file and/or directory names into the cmd.exe, (Command Prompt), window, or are you dragging and dropping them. If the former, what is the current directory at the time you are using the batch file, and are you typing the fully qualified absolute paths?