# List the blobs that will be sent to the remote repository by 'git push' in descending order of size

Tags: git

I'm having trouble with [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) taking too long, and the remote repository terminating the connection. It is a [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) project and we are in a bit of a mess working out which files Unity needs and which are safe to put in the [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore).

Is there a way in git to list the blobs that the `git push` command will transfer to the remote repository, including their path and size? (It'd be great to list them in descending size order too.)

Comment: OS ? Where the git is involved ? Possibly you are looking for `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456550/how-to-find-the-n-largest-files-in-git-repository`

Comment: Windows 10, but I'm using Git from Bash so I'm hoping that the answer is not OS specific. Thanks for the link