# Git tries to push oversized files that are no longer in repo nor in cache

Tags: git, github, commit

**Summary:** I made a git commit that contained oversized files and, when trying to push, got the dreaded "large files" error. I restructured the repo to have a new top-level directory that no longer contains any large files, but I still get the "large files" error when trying to push. I tried various common solutions (below), but git keeps trying to push files that are outside the new top-level repo.

**Details on what I did:**

1. I manually removed the .git and .gitignore files to my desired new directory, as described [here](https://dev.to/hiboabd/how-to-change-the-root-folder-of-your-github-repo-4ccb).
2. I confirmed that the new root directory was successfully recognized via `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.
3. I tried to push to the remote again (`git push origin main`), but got the error `File <filepath> is 102.90 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`, where `<filepath>` is a path inside the old directory, not the new one.
4. I tried to remove the file from the cache via `git rm -r --cached <filepath>` (as described in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-can-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitign)), but
   this yields the error `fatal: <filepath> is outside repository`.
5. I reset via `git reset HEAD~`, then tried again to push, but I got the same error as above.
6. I tried to filter the branch history to remove commits involving the large file (`stitched.csv`) via `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch stitched.csv' HEAD`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-the-git-repository/46615578#46615578). Then I tried to push again and still got same error, again referring to `stitched.csv`.

In practice, I have quite a few oversized files, so I would really rather not have to remove each one from the cache manually. I have made numerous good commits since the ones that involved large files.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `git push` command pushes *commits*. Every commit has a full snapshot of every file. This is not a cache: this is the fundamental way that Git works. If some commit has a large file, it has that file, forever, because no commit can ever change. If you don't like that commit, you can stop using it—and all its descendants—and avoid `git push`-ing that commit (note that an attempt to push one of its descendants will take *that* commit too, which is why you have to ditch all the descendants).

Comment: There are some tools specifically for rewriting repositories to ditch large files: The BFG and the newfangled `git filter-repo` both have support for this. Filter-repo is the replacement for the now-deprecated, hard-to-use `filter-branch`, but filter-repo isn't actually included in Git distributions: you have to fetch and install it. (Same for The BFG.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you need to filter and remove those large files from your Git history.

The more recent option is now the [third-party tool `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (with its [installation process](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md), and using Python)

In order to not have to list every large file, you can determine a size above which you want *any* file to be removed:

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 2M
```

Replace "`2M`" (two Mo) by an appropriate size: see "[How to find the N largest files in a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9456550/6309)".