# Fix GitHub repository with corrupted files: "inflate returned -3"

Tags: git, github, corruption

**The Problem.** Recently I've been facing the following kind of errors whenever I try to push to git in a few repositories I have of PDF/DjVu files:

```
Enumerating objects: 153, done.
Counting objects: 100% (153/153), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (152/152), done.
remote: error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
remote: fatal: pack has bad object at offset 909244: inflate returned -3
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To github.com:A-GitHub-Organisation/Algebraic-Geometry.git
! \[remote rejected\] main -\> main (failed)z
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:A-GitHub-Organisation/Algebraic-Geometry.git'
```

I think the source of the problem is that I had these repositories on my NAS for over a year, and believe the files in the repository (not only in the .git folder) got corrupted, although they still open in PDF viewers such as evince or zathura.

**Failed Attempts at a Solution.** Here's what I've tried and didn't work:

1. Make a fresh new repository and transfer all the files to the new repository.
2. Run `git gc`, `git gc --aggressive`, `git-repair`, `git fsck --full`.

Attempt (1) didn't work: it seems the `inflate returned -3` is related to the files themselves, not any corruption going on inside the `.git` folder.

Attempt (2) also didn't work: I still get the same error.

**A Successful But Clumsy Solution.** The last thing I tried―and which did work but in too clumsy a way―is to first commit the files with `git add .;git commit -m "something"` and then leave `watch -d -n 2 'git push'` running for a while. This way the `offset #number` in the line

`remote: fatal: pack has bad object at offset 909244: inflate returned -3`

tends to change, e.g. here's a sample output I got:

```
remote: fatal: pack has bad object at offset 51177059: inflate returned -3
remote: fatal: pack has bad object at offset 1017: inflate returned -3    
remote: fatal: pack has bad object at offset 6170201: inflate returned -3
remote: fatal: pack has bad object at offset 14620489: inflate returned -3
```

However, eventually the `git push` finally goes through after a couple attempts (usually ranging from 1 to 10+). I've also found that the amount of attempts required for the push to go through seem to be proportional to the total size of the commit (which is part of why I think the issue is that some files got lightly corrupted).

**The Question.** What's going on with these errors? What can I do to fix them and have the files pushed normally?

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: Hi @VonC! I'm using version 2.39.2.

Comment: Are you connecting to the remote with HTTPS or SSH?

Comment: Hi Jim! I'm connecting via SSH.

Comment: How big is your .git folder? How big are the pdf files in question? (see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9504361/1978365 to answer the later question)

Comment: Hi @Kim, although the average size of the files in the repository is not so big (3.5 MB), there are a number of large files: 1) The top 10 biggest files in the repository are 96, 62, 61, 60, 58, 54, 48, 46, 46, and 46 MB. 2) The .git folder is 5.8 GB 3) There are 154 files weighing ≥ 10 MB, 42 files weighing ≥ 25 MB, and 6 files weighing ≥ 50 MB.

Comment: Lastly, one curious thing that happened was that I tried reassembling the largest repo (IIRC the .git folder weighted about 21 GB) where such a problem occurred yesterday into smaller repos and the incidence of the `inflate returned -3` error was significantly lower, and I only got it once instead of dozens of times. I think this might have been because I had already rebuilt it into another repo and used GitHub's online file upload feature for a bunch of files, which +

Comment: + I imagine might have affected some of the corruption errors in the files weighing ≤ 25 MB, or at least how git deals with them. I'm still unsure about the precise source cause of the error, though.

Comment: By the way, thank you for the pointer to SO9504361, @Kim! That was super useful in enumerating the size of the files in the repo!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a tool called git-repair yoou can get it in the ubuntu terminal by typing in (sudo apt install git-repair) that can attempt to repair your repository from remote sources. You can run it with the --force option to overwrite any local changes that may conflict with the remote. You may also need to delete any broken references (find .git/refs -size 0 -delete -print) and clean up any dangling commits (git gc --prune=now) before running git-repair. After that, you can try to fetch the latest state from the remote (git fetch) and see if the problem is solved1.

Another way is to clone a fresh copy of your repository from GitHub and then move the .git folder from the cloned repo to your original repo. This will replace your corrupted .git folder with a new one that should be working. However, this may also overwrite any local changes that you have not pushed yet, so be careful with this method.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I've tried `git-repair` before, but didn't run the two other commands before it (although I did run `git gc --aggressive`). I'll try it again as soon as I can. Unfortunately replacing the `.git` folder doesn't quite work: I think there's something corrupted in the files themselves that then propagates to the .git folder each time, making the latter corrupt again, with the `export returned -3` error returning.