# How To Get Only Certain Object Types Back From Git LS-Files

Tags: git, command-line-arguments, ls, file-type, git-ls-files

I'm trying to see what opportunities I might have to refactor some code.
So I'm looking to see how to search my repository for the longest files to consider.
But how can you use [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)'s to return back just a certain [`filename`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#_field_names) like java-files `*.java`?

I'm not understanding the documentation yet. And, I could use some rephrasing to understand this.
I've tried running variations of `--format='*.java'`, `--format=objecttype *.java` `*.java`, `grep java`, and others. I have the rest of the code `git ls-files | grep java | xargs ls -l | sort -nrk5 | head -n 10` from ["How can I find the N largest files in a Git repository?" SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456550/how-can-i-find-the-n-largest-files-in-a-git-repository).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine.

`git ls-files  | grep ".*java" | xargs ls -alh | sort -rhk5 | head -n 10`

I've replaced instances of `-n` with `-h` which gives you the filesize in a nice human-readable format.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 joel  staff    65K Nov 20 15:18 src/com/crawlmb/keyboard/CrawlKeyboardView.java
-rw-r--r--  1 joel  staff    17K Nov 20 15:18 src/com/crawlmb/ConfigEditor.java
-rw-r--r--  1 joel  staff    16K Nov 20 15:18 src/com/crawlmb/activity/PreferencesActivity.java
(skipped remaining entries)
```

I noticed that if you're searching for smaller patterns like for `.c` files,  replace `".*c"` with `".*\.c"` for more precision. Otherwise, I got results having entries like "do**c**/Guidebook.txt" because of the 'c' occurrence.