# Browse disk usage of git staging area

Tags: git

I want to version control my home directory in `git`.

I've used `ncdu` to find the largest sub-directories and from there built a `.gitignore` which I hope excludes the largest and most useless parts of my home directory (eg `.gem/`, `.cache/`, `.cabal/`, `tmp/`).

After doing a `git add $HOME`, how can I browse the index / cache / staging area with respect to disk usage?

Ideally, I'm after something interactive like `ncdu` where I can drill down into sub-directories.

Comment: Are you interested in the size of the repository, or are you asking for the staging area (aka "index") specifically? Or the size of the changes size the last commit?

Comment: Size of the index. Imagine I've just done `git init; git add $HOME` and I want to have a `ncdu`-like look at what's in the index / cache / staging area.

Comment: If you are going to do this, be especially sure to exclude directories like `.ssh`, or be meticulous on your permissions... or check out `etckeeper` which can be told to manage `$HOME` instead. Also, don't push to anywhere you wouldn't trust with your `ssh` keys!

Comment: The index itself is a cache of `stat` data plus some Git-specific data including the hash ID of each "blob" that is now already added to the repository. You can examine the sizes of the objects, but even that may not be terribly useful since you won't know for sure how many times the object is shared, nor how the object will shrink once packed.

Answer (score 1):

Stash data store in git-dir.

Default the git store data in folder .git (git-dir).

> The latest stash you created is stored in refs/stash; older stashes
>   are found in the reflog of this reference and can be named using the
>   usual reflog syntax (e.g. stash@{0} is the most recently created
>   stash, stash@{1} is the one before it, stash@{2.hours.ago} is also
>   possible).

Comment: Won't this be a bunch of sha checksums in a new `.git` location? How would I browse this as a directory tree?

Answer (score 0):

The size of the index itself won't be relevant, since I detail in "[What does the git index contain EXACTLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086986/6309)":

> The state is "virtual" in the sense that it does not necessarily have to, and often does not, match the files in the working tree.

What you can do is... make a commit (you can always `git reset @~` to cancel the commit and redo it later)

Then, as mentioned in "[git find fat commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557398/6309)":

```
git diff-tree -r -c -M -C --no-commit-id @     # get new blobs for HEAD commit
git cat-file --batch-check << blob ids         # get size of each blob
```

That will use [`git cat-file` bach output](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file#_batch_output) to print information about them, including `objectsize:disk`.
If no format is specified, the default format is `%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(objectsize)`.