# ./.git/objects folder contains huge size files

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am using EC2 box with 4GB RAM and disk space of 8GB. I inspected my directories all of which were supposed to contain python scripts. I found that my /.git folder is 1.8GB in size. Most of the space was taken by ./.git/objects folder. Out of that too very few folders are in ~200MBs.Is it too much of a size? Can I just delete those folders? I am running out of disk space so cannot install more packages using pip.

I am 40 commits ahead on EC2. I don't want to push those commits because there is something in the history which is huge in size(some 100MB which I unknowingly committed) and it does not allow me to do so. I looked at the solution online and found that it is not so easy. Given the amount of time that I have I decided to edit scripts on my local machine and push those to git and then pull them into my remote machine.

Comment: That is the actual data `git` uses to track revisions; you can't delete them. You may want to research how to purge the 100MB file from Git's history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at this thread to find out what happened (possible duplicate): [How to find/identify large files/commits in Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622179/how-to-find-identify-large-files-commits-in-git-history)

Then take a look at [BFG Repo Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to clean up your repository.

You should avoid commiting binary files because even deleted, they will always be in the .git/objects folder, and you should never delete files from there yourself.