# Finding Large Files in Mercurial Repository

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert

Similar to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622179/how-to-find-identify-large-files-commits-in-git-history) but for mercurial. I'd like to find the files that are most contributing to the size of my mercurial repository.

I intend to use hg convert to create a new, smaller repository.  I'm just not sure yet which files are contributing to the repository size.  They could be files that have already been deleted.

What is a good way to find these anywhere in the repository history?  There are over 20,000 commits. I'm thinking a powershell script, but I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check `hg help fileset`. Something like

```
hg files "set:size('>1M')"
```

should do the trick for you. You might need to operate over all revisions, though as it only operates on one revision. In bash I'd try something like

```
for i in `hg log -r"all()" "set:size('>400k')" --template="{rev}\n"`; do hg files -r$i "set:size('>400k')"; done | sort | uniq
```

might do the trick. Maybe it can be optimized as it's currently a bit duplication and might run for quite a bit; on the OpenTTD repository with 22000 commits it took on my laptop just short of 10 minutes.

(Also check hg help on `templates`, `files` and `grep`)

Comment: Thanks, that works wonders. I am using windows. For completeness the powershell script is `hg log -r"all()" "set:size('>1024k')" --template="{rev}\n" | Foreach { hg files -r $_ "set:size('>1024k')" >> results.txt; get-content results.txt |
 sort | get-unique > results2.txt; Remove-Item results.txt; Move-Item results2.txt results.txt }` and the bat file would be `for /F %i in ('hg log -r"all()" "set:size('>1024k')" --template="{rev}\n"') DO hg files -r %i "set:size('>1024k')" >> results.txt` (that doesn't sort/filter though)