# Mercurial: Find and delete folder from repository history

Tags: mercurial

A former colleague somehow made a large commit in a mercurial repo and now its very large. I haven't found the commit but bitbucket reports that the repo is > 1gb which it shouldn't be.

Is there any way to find which revision added alle the large files and delete it from history?

Comment: Do you know the path of these large files?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278136/finding-large-files-in-mercurial-repository

Comment: @PVitt The path is "/Media"