# how to reduce pack files in git folder?

Tags: git, object, github, gitlab, pack

I Have a problem in my gitlab repo,
Don't know they created pack file with large memory around 20 GB that affected my server device space

I need to remove those file

please help me to reduce or remove those file, and what will be the effect after removing this files

Comment: XY problem. The pack files are large because you have commits with large files. See [How to find/identify large files/commits in Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622179/how-to-find-identify-large-files-commits-in-git-history) and [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository).

Comment: what if  I use " git gc --prune=now --aggressive "  command, what will happen after this? does it remove all my last commits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)