# While uploading a php project github gives error of file size

Tags: github

When i uploading a php project into existing repository which itself contains another project. Github through this error:
"Yowza, that’s a big file. Try again with a file smaller than 25MB."
My project folder size is in Kb's even not in Mb's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and [list all the files of your current repository, sorted by size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544963/6309).

Chances are, you have, by mistake, included one large binary.

Answer (score -1):

look, it's mb if kb is above 1024kb!

1024kb == 1MB
so if you have 35000kb > 25000mb then Github tells you this error!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).