# Find largest files/ largest branches across git repo

Tags: git, github

I have accidentally committed one binary file in one of my branches which take around 8Mb, Is there a way to find out

1. Which branch is it?
2. Which commit is it?

So that I can delete the corresponding branch from Github

Comment: I think this could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622179/how-to-find-identify-large-commits-in-git-history

Comment: @Sami The linked post is mainly a way to filter files along size. When you know the file name/path, this is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --oneline -- path/to/file
```

will output a list of all commits modifying this path.

If you just introduced the file, you'll have only one commit, but even if you made a few commits since, you could then use the hash(es) found there to list branches involved :

```
git branch -a --contains <commitHash>
```