# fatal: the remote hung up unexpectedly. Can’t push things to my git repo

Tags: html, css, git, repository, hung

My first problem looked like this:

```
Writing objects: 60% (9/15)
```

It freezed there for some time with very low upload speed (in kb/s), then, after long time, gave this message:

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I found something what seemed to be a solution:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

This created a new problem that looks like this:

```
MacBook-Pro-Liana:LC | myWebsite Liana$ git config http.postBuffer 524288000
MacBook-Pro-Liana:LC | myWebsite Liana$ git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 15, done.
Counting objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 116.01 MiB | 25.16 MiB/s, done.
Total 15 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Please help, I have no idea what’s going on...

Answer (score 0):

First, [Git 2.25.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849424/6309) made it clear that:

> Users in a wide variety of situations find themselves with HTTP push problems.
>
> Oftentimes these issues are due to antivirus software, filtering proxies, or other man-in-the-middle situations; other times, they are due to simple unreliability of the network.
>
> This works for none of the aforementioned situations and is only useful in a small, highly restricted number of cases: essentially, when the connection does not properly support HTTP/1.1.
>
> Raising this is not, in general, an effective solution for most push problems, but can increase memory consumption significantly since the entire buffer is allocated even for small pushes.

Second, it depends on your actual remote (GitHub? GitLab? BitBucket? On-premise server). Said remote server might have an incident in progress.

Comment: I use GitHub... And I have successfully uploaded several projects, they are very similar. No such problems I had before...

Comment: @LianaA Do you have many commits to push? or one of those commits might be too big? (you can mist those objects with https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544963/6309)

Comment: not really... there are only like 8 files, 3 html, 1 css, 2 img and 2 gifs