# AWS CodeCommit keeps unreferenced binary blob even though branch was deleted

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

Let's say I have pushed a branch containing a 100 MB binary blob file to my AWS CodeCommit by mistake, which has now made cloning the repo very slow.

I have deleted the branch containing it, but cloning the repo is still slow, and [the binary blob is still there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622179/how-to-find-identify-large-commits-in-git-history) even though [I have verified it's unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob) from any branch or commit.

How do I force AWS CodeCommit to garbage-collect it? Or at least, can I count on CodeCommit to eventually garbage-collect it (in two weeks, or whatever time interval it uses)?

Answer (score 1):

> Or at least, can I count on CodeCommit to eventually garbage-collect it (in two weeks, or whatever time interval it uses)?

Yes, if the blob is truly unreachable, CodeCommit should garbage collect it eventually. Reading [the docs for `git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc):

> When common porcelain operations that create objects are run, they will check whether the repository has grown substantially since the last maintenance, and if so run `git gc` automatically.

So assuming that CodeCommit executes the code that does this, say by directly executing `git add` from the command line, then it will run garbage collection automatically.

Comment: "say by directly executing git add from the command line" - could you clarify that? I'm asking because I don't have SSH access to CodeCommit. I can execute `git add` on my local repo, but I can only push to the remote CodeCommit server.

Comment: @sashoalm I'm not familiar with CodeCommit, but I assume it has a web interface similar to those that I use with GitHub or BitBucket. When I wrote those particular words, I had in mind that when you take actions through that interface, CodeCommit executes shell commands on its server. For example, when you make a pull request and then click the "merge" button, under the hood it probably executes a `git merge` command.

Comment: @sashoalm Even a `git push` will "create objects" in the remote repository. So the way I read the documentation, `git gc` will eventually run.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was with the script from [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob). It was listing commits that reference the blob, but ONLY IF those commits are in the currently checked out branch.

My blob was being referenced by another (different) branch! Once I removed that, the blob disappeared immediately from AWS CodeCommit, so I was wrong to think CodeCommit keeps blobs around even when not referenced.