# git: unable to reduce .git folder size

Tags: git

This is the size of my .git folder:

```
$ du -sh .git
321M    .git
```

There are a couple of huge files accidentally commited there in the past.

Through some [bizarre magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622179/how-to-find-identify-large-commits-in-git-history) I found the cuplrits and their blobs:

```
$ git rev-list --objects --all |   git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' |   sed -n 's/^blob //p' |   sort --numeric-sort --key=2 |   cut -c 1-12,41- |   $(command -v gnumfmt || echo numfmt) --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest


....
5c48fadaee41  492MiB android/java_pid3568.hprof
...
```

And the author of these commits:

```
git log --all --full-history -- "android/java_pid3568.hprof"

commit cac160ab39b9c70f3d05f8194be8c3c0657161ad
Author: Incore <xxxx@mail.ru>
Date:   Thu Dec 10 18:34:34 2020 +0300

commit fc0cfc2f32ddd0f927169ad0514213f79795dd63
Author: Incore <xxxx@mail.ru>
Date:   Tue Dec 8 21:26:17 2020 +0300
```

After this, I tried to rewrite my history removing this file:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter   'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch android/java_pid3568.hprof'   --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all



Rewrite fc0cfc2f32ddd0f927169ad0514213f79795dd63 (19/376) (1 seconds passed, remaining 18 predicted)    rm 'android/java_pid3568.hprof'
Rewrite 540ced9097b7090bfd68279515178bf060db93ee (19/376) (1 seconds passed, remaining 18 predicted)    rm 'android/java_pid3568.hprof'
```

Now my `git log` shows there is no such file in history:

```
git log --all --full-history -- "android/java_pid3568.hprof"

... empty response
```

However, the size of my  `.git` folder has not been reduced:

```
$ du -sh .git
321M    .git
```

why is that?

Comment: Do you need to run the garbage collection?

Comment: I ran `git gc` but still my `.git` folder is 321M large.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how filter branch works, but if any commit which still contains those files is reachable, then the git repo won't reduce in size.

Comment: if `git log` searching for those files shows empty response - this should mean that there aren't any commits containing this file, are there?

Comment: Try using `git log` on every branch? local and remote branches

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but nothing there https://prnt.sc/107ofsu. Locally I only have master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commits containing the huge file are still handled by the reflog so they can't be garbage collected just by a `git gc`.

You could find some good commands in the answers to this question:
[How to remove unreferenced blobs from my git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repo)

like

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

or

```
git -c gc.reflogExpire=0 -c gc.reflogExpireUnreachable=0 -c gc.rerereresolved=0 -c gc.rerereunresolved=0 -c gc.pruneExpire=now gc
```

PS: oh, and it's always a good idea to use https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ to do this kind of cleaning. Much easier, secure and quicker than filter-branch.