# Merge git commits into daily commits

Tags: git

I have an org file where I ended up git committing on every save. This has resulted in a very large .git directory which is understandable, but it is not the right granularity for my purposes.

```
$ git count-objects -vH
..
count: 27393
size: 51.66 GiB
```

Is it possible to go back through my commits and automatically coalesce commits made on the same day, week or something similar so that I can look see when changes happen without wasting space on multiple commits a day?

Comment: What is your biggest problem? The repo size or "the right granularity"? If it's the repo size, [the Linux kernel has tens of thousands of commits but is sized less than 5GB](https://github.blog/2018-03-05-measuring-the-many-sizes-of-a-git-repository/). Usually [a big repo is caused by committing large files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10622179/9157799), not number of commits.

Comment: @MImamPratama I agree with your question. Note the [linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) is now over one million commits and is about 3.5 GB in size.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
git reset --soft $(git rev-list -n 1 --before="yesterday" HEAD) && git commit -m 'daily commit'
```

this will make a single comit of everything that was comitted since yesterday. Doing so every morning may do the trick.