# Gitlab clone is extremely slow, what i should do?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ee

[image: [enter image description here]]

Result of the clone:

```bash
remote: Counting objects: 100% (250/250), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (215/215), done.
remote: Total 250 (delta 30), reused 250 (delta 30), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (250/250), 3.47 MiB | **25.00 KiB/s**, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (30/30), done.
```

My problem is /gitlab v15.2.5/ clone speed only Kib/s,

It was alright few weeks ago. I checked my vps RAM and CPU usage: that was normal. What should I do?

Comment: Does this happen on all projects? On all PCs you clone to? Did you try rebooting gitlab server?

Comment: 3.47gb in objects smells like a binary that should not be included in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, consider a [shallow clone](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/), just to test if you can get an initial clone faster (with a lower depth).

But consider also, once you have finally cloned the full repository, [identifying the largest commits in your repository Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10622179/6309). Making sure you have trimmed the biggest file could help speed up the initial clone.

Comment: Also see if you’ve checked in a huge binary, perhaps by accident by not ignoring something that’s a build output. You can do this by examining file sizes in your local repo.

Comment: @Kit True. That is what [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10622179/6309) I mention in the answer is for ("examining file sizes in your local repo")