# How can I revert a GitHub repository to its initial empty state?

Tags: git

I created a file in my GitHub repository, which was initially empty using the GitHub website. Now, I would like to revert the repository back to its original empty state, removing the file that was added and clearing the commit history.

I would appreciate any guidance or instructions.

I tried to use `git reset -- HEAD^` but it didn't work.

Comment: Why not just delete the directory and re-run `git init`?

Comment: I'm not sure which directory you're referring to. Currently, I don't have any local files; I only have the remote repository. I would prefer not to delete the repository and recreate it for two reasons. Firstly, I want to understand how to achieve the desired outcome without resorting to deletion. Secondly, I don't have sufficient permissions and I don't want to bother my boss just to avoid an extra commit.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote repository"? How are you running `git reset` _remotely_?

Comment: Indeed, I cloned the repository in order to try the command, but it didn't yield the desired result. By mentioning the remote repository, I simply meant that I haven't made any commits locally on my cloned copy.

Comment: I guess you could easily remove the repo in github and create it again.... but that's my _assumption_.

Comment: I would just do an amend commit as your first commit followed by a force push :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question answered here [How to completely clear git repository, without deleting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578581/how-to-completely-clear-git-repository-without-deleting-it)
**TL;DR**:

```
git checkout <first commit hash>
git rm -r *
touch README
git add README
git commit --amend
git push -f
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped! I didn't actually need to checkout to the first commit since there was only one, but the rest of the solution worked like a charm. So I deleted the initial file, amended it with some extra changes, and then force-pushed everything to get things back on track.