# Remove git history older than a specific tag

Tags: git, github

I have a repo with a large number of commits and tags and I want to remove the history older than a certain tag so it that the repo size will be much smaller. How can I do that?

Previous questions do not identify with the objective of removing history older than a certain tag nor offer a concise solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git remove history commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091928/git-remove-history-commit)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of truncating the history permanently on the server-side, you could pass `--depth` to `git clone` to truncate it on the client side only. To determine the depth / number of commits since a tag you can use `git rev-list $tag..HEAD --count`.

Comment: Thank you @sscuberth. I agree that is not desirable to destructively remove history. Regardless, when it truly no longer matters or you have forked from an upstream where a significant amount of the original history can be pruned away because it has become cruft, I want to know how this can be done properly. Depth must be predetermined before it can be applied. Are there there better ways to do this permanently?

Comment: There already are at least [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20152495/1127485) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13092954/1127485) that seem to cover your use case. Both involve using `rebase` / `replace` and force-pushing, followed by `gc` to prune stale history.