# Is it safe to delete merged branch in git

Tags: git, github, merge

Let's say we develop a feature in branch, think it's complete, merge it to master and delete the branch. Later bug is discovered in this specific feature and someone goes and resets the HEAD on global repository (which you shouldn't do). Now, we could have fixed that bug but don't have the branch anymore and whole feature is lost. Is there a way to restore those changes, and is it overall good idea to preserve feature branches after merge for a while?

Comment: Nobody has a clone that still contains the merge commit?

Answer (score 4):

Assume before the merge the commit history was like this.
[image: before the merge]

After merging `feature` to `master`, it became this.
[image: after the merge]

And now the branch `feature` has been deleted and it's been like this.
[image: delete the feature branch]

As we can see, the commit history of `feature` is still there though the ref `feature` has gone. A branch ref is just a variable that stores the sha1 hashes of the commits that it points to from then to now.

`M` is the merge commit(only if it was a true merge, a non-fast-forward merge) that was created when merging `feature` to `master`. It has two parents, `D` the first parent, which `master` was pointing to, and `F` the second parent, which `feature` was pointing to. If we merged `master` to `feature` and created `M`, then `F` is the first parent, and `D` the second.

The first parent can be referred to by `M^` and the second parent via `M^2`.

Now if you want to recreate the branch ref `feature`, supposing `M`'s value is `af2343242`, you could run `git branch feature af2343242^2`. And it's going to be like this again.
[image: after the merge]

> is it overall good idea to preserve feature branches after merge for a while

It depends. Some believe it's good to keep all the changes that were once there, including all the commits and all the branches, tags, etc. After all, these are the precious legacy of a project.

Answer (score 2):

### Example

Use ***release branches***. Say, when you reach a significant milestone in your projects development (completed and merged a new feature) into a production etc.

Create a tag

```
git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "v1.0.0"
```

Now, say you've continued working and began a new feature and after a while you've realised there is a bug which has been introduced with that feature you've merged before. How to get back to it after you've merged and deleted it?

Let's get back to the tag we've created upon merging the new feature

```
git checkout v1.0.0
```

We cannot commit directly to ***tag***, but we can make a new branch out of it (*release branch*).

```
git checkout -b rb1.0.0
```

Now we can apply ***hot fix*** then add and commit our changes to the branch

```
git add <file> <file> 
git commit -m "<hot fix message>"
```

At this point all what's left is to merge the ***hot fix***. So, we go back to `master` branch and merge the ***release branch***

```
git checkout master
git merge rb1.0.0 -m "Merged <hot fix message>"
```

Just to keep it tidy we will also remove the ***release branch*** at this point.

```
git branch -d rb1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is generally a good idea to preserve feature branches for a while, at least until you are 100% sure you will never go back.

It doesn't hurt anything or take up any resources. A branch is only a little sticky note pointing to a commit. The only effect it has inside of `git` is that it prevents the garbage collector from irrecoverably removing the commit it points to (and its ancestors).

For your current scenario, I would simply create a branch (or tag) pointing to the bugged version of `master`, then reset master back behind the merge point. Then you are all set - `git` will not automatically delete your otherwise "lost" branch, and you can come back to it when you are ready.

Of course, if you want to make a "real" branch from it, you need to find the commit on the branch side just before the merge, and do `git branch mybranch <hash>`, that would probably be optimal.

Comment: *It doesn't hurt anything or take up any resources* It takes up cognitive resources, in the form of that old "WTF" feeling when you notice your repo has 79 branches, some dating from six months ago.

Comment: Why would the number of branches in your repo take up cognitive resources?

Comment: "Usually cutting off a branch will free only a very small, unpredictable, space." got this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722076/git-disk-usage-per-branch, I concur with @Anoe that it doesn't hurt anything or take up any resources.

Comment: Useful answer, but strongly disagree with 70+ merged, stale branches not taking up "cognitive" resources, if I'm looking through my branch list on Github, I'm expecting to see branches which are actively worked on, I don't want to sift through 70 branches (regardless of ordering), just to find that one branch I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover all your commits using reflog. See the below link.

http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html

**Excerpts from the link:**

For example, consider below repo:

```
$ git show-ref -h HEAD
  7c61179cbe51c050c5520b4399f7b14eec943754 HEAD

$ git reset --hard HEAD^
  HEAD is now at 39ba87b Fixing about and submit pages so they don't look stupid

$ git show-ref -h HEAD
  39ba87bf28b5bb223feffafb59638f6f46908cac HEAD
```

Now HEAD is moved back by 1 commit. Lets see if git knows the removed commit.

```
$ git reflog
  39ba87b... HEAD@{0}: HEAD~1: updating HEAD
  7c61179... HEAD@{1}: pull origin master: Fast forward
  [... lots of other refs ...]
```

So, we now have our SHA1: 7c61179. If we want to get immediately apply it back onto our current branch, doing a git merge will recover the commit:

```
$ git merge 7c61179
  Updating 39ba87b..7c61179
  Fast forward
    css/screen.css |    4 ++++
    submit.html    |    4 ++--
    2 files changed, 6 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

This command will bring your lost changes back and make sure that HEAD is pointing at the commit. From here you can continue to work as normal!

Comment: Updated the answer. Thank you for the direction.