# ANT exec task with rsync does not show update output

Tags: ant, exec, rsync

When I execute an ANT `exec` task to run `rsync --progress /from/path/foo.txt to/path`, it shows the progress bar like this:
 32768   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00

But never updates it.

If I execute rsync command without ant, the progress bar is updated.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior.

The output of rsync refreshes the same line. For example, it may output:

```
Precent finsihed: 0%\r
Precent finsihed: 1%\r
Precent finsihed: 2%\r
```

So that the "Percent finished:" part and the percent ("%") will remain still on the screen, while the number changes.

However, there are some problem handling such kind of output in Java, check this question:

[Reading other process' **unbuffered** output stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963478/reading-other-process-unbuffered-output-stream)

Maybe there are some methods to handle such output, but obviously Ant hasn't implemented it.