# Call Ruby shotgun executable from a Ruby script and open the browser to root URL

Tags: ruby, process, shotgun

I am trying to call [`shotgun`](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun) from a Ruby script. I want to both spin up the server and open the default browser (I'm on OS X Mavericks) to the root of the site.  `shotgun` provides the `--browse` option for this, but I find it doesn't work, either from the Ruby script or from the terminal.  Therefore I need to execute two commands from my script-- `shotgun MYAPPFILE` followed by `open ROOTURL`. The problem is that the `shotgun MYAPPFILE` command starts the shotgun process but does not exit, so `open ROOTURL` is never executed.

Also, I notice when I use backticks to call `shotgun`, none of the normal `shotgun` output is printed to STDOUT. But when I use `system("shotgun MYAPPFILE")`, I do see this output.

I want to start the server, open the browser to the root URL, and see the shotgun output. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `PTY` (pseudo-terminal):

```
require 'pty'

PTY.spawn "shotgun app.rb" do |stdout, stdin, pid|
  begin
    trap('INT') { Process.kill("INT", pid) }
    `open http://localhost:9393`
    stdout.each { |li| puts li }
  rescue PTY::ChildExited
    puts "Shotgun exited!"
  end
end
```

The code above will exit when you hit Ctrl-c (i.e. send an interrupt). `PTY` is needed here as opposed to a normal process for reasons having to do with flushing of output.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154846/continuously-read-from-stdout-of-external-process-in-ruby?rq=1) for details.