# How to read stdout unbuffered with Open#popen3 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unix, io

I'm running a process using `popen3`, and trying to read the stdout stream. I want to be able to detect each character as it's put into stdout, but even using `stdout.getc`, I'm only able to get any output once there's a newline.

Any tips? I've seen this answered with `stdin.getc`, but not stdout.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that most programs when run through a pipe, which is what happens with `popen`, will be run using buffered output.

But what you are looking for is unbuffered output. Unbuffered output only happens when the proccess is attached to a PTY. I.e. a shell.

When you attach the process to a pipe the output will be buffered unless the process is explicitly calling `flush` during its output processing.

You have a few options:

1. If you have control over the source code that you run with `popen` then force a `flush` call on stdout after each output sequence.
2. You could try and run the command under `stdbuf -o0`, which tries to force unbuffered output.
   See this answer:
   [Force line-buffering of stdout when piping to tee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee/11337109#11337109).
   However that is not guaranteed to work for all programs.
3. You could try to use the Ruby `PTY` library instead of `popen` to make the program run under a pseudo-terminal, and hence run unbuffered. See this answer:
   [Continuously read from STDOUT of external process in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154846/continuously-read-from-stdout-of-external-process-in-ruby/1162850#1162850)

Option 3 is most likely to work with any program you want to run and monitor, while the other options may or may not work depending on the program you are running and if you have access to the source code of that program.

Comment: _Unbuffered output only happens when the proccess is attached to a PTY. I.e. a shell._ The default of glibc is to make stderr unbuffered but to do *line-buffering* on stdout (not unbuffered!) if stdout is connected to an "interactive device" (i.e. a terminal, not only PTYs). See   http://stackoverflow.com/a/3746795/601203. A shell is _not_ a PTY.