# Ruby Open3.popen3 hangs when trying to get output

Tags: ruby, popen3

I am trying to work through the following example given in my course notes:

```
require 'open3' 
sin,sout,serr=Open3.popen3('nslookup')
sin.puts "www.google.co.nz" 
print(sout.gets)
```

For some reason the code is hanging. I tried executing it in interactive mode and when I entered the last line and then pressed control c, reentering the command worked. Please assist.

Comment: Try closing the input stream via `sin.close` before reading the command's output.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to read stdout unbuffered with Open#popen3 in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22783593/479863)?

Comment: Thanks @Stefan... Out of interest why I need to close sin?

Comment: @TeereraiMarange this was asked before, see the linked question for further explanation!