# Collecting Exe printf outputs from system call in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to store the printf output of an exe file that I call by system(foo.exe) in ruby and get the exit status. How would I do that?

Comment: [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154846/continuously-read-from-stdout-of-external-process-in-ruby) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) is the best way to do this.

```
require 'open3'
Open3.popen3('foo.exe') do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thr|
  status = thr.value
  output = stdout.read
  errors = stderr.read
end
```