# Check if stdout contains output?

Tags: ruby

I have a `client.rb` program which prints a few lines of text and then pauses for user input. I'm trying to wrap this using `PTY.spawn` (or another subprocess library, if the functionality's not available here).

Using `stdout.readline` I can print the few lines of output. The problem is, once the output's done (and it's waiting for my input), `stdout.readline` just hangs.

```
require 'pty'
PTY.spawn("ruby client.rb") do |stdout, stdin, thread|
  until (line=stdout.readline).empty?; puts line; end
end
```

I am looking for a method on `stdout` that will return `nil` or `''` if there's nothing there. I suppose I could use `rescue` and `Timeout` but I'm hoping there's a better way.

I should note that I've had the same issue using other methods to read from `stdout`: `each_line`, `each`, `read`, `readlines`. In all these cases, it hangs for > 30 seconds then raises:

```
Errno::EIO Exception: Input/output error @ io_fillbuf
```

After this error is raised, trying to read from `stdout` again causes the same error to be raised, but now it happens immediately.

I've seen in various tutorials (i.e. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1162850/2981429)) that the `Errno::EIO` can be rescued. However it's not working for me. Even if I command `client.rb` to print more output, trying to read from `stdout` always shows this error once it's been raised the first time.