# Push tags with git subtree push

Tags: git, subtree

I have main repo with many sub-repos. If I do some edits to sub-repos, I can push them to sub-repos using the `git subtree push --prefix=path/to/code Repo master --squash`. Recently, I've added new tag to main repo `git tag 1.0` -> `git push --tags`. Unfortunately, sub-repos don't include this tag. How can I push this tag to sub-repos? I found the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911466/how-to-push-tags-with-git-subtree), but it doesn't solve my problem, because I can't merge sub-repos to main repo.

Answer (score 0):

Tags are just pointers to commits. If the commit doesn't exist in your sub-repo (which I'm quite sure it doesn't, and shouldn't), then you can't have the tag in your repo either (it wouldn't be pointing to anything meaningful).

The whole point of a sub repository is that you want to treat it as its own repo without reference to the "parent". So if you want a `1.0` tag in your sub-repo, you'll have to create a new tag in your sub-repo named `1.0`, point it to an appropriate commit that exists in your sub-repo, and then push it to the sub-repo's origin.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Could you give me a hint how to add and push tags in sub-repos?

Comment: I can push tags to sub-repo, but to do so, I have to split sub-repo from main repo to separate folder. In this folder I can use `git tag 1.0` -> `git push --tags` to add and push tags to sub-repo. Is there some simpler way?