# How do we tag a single folder from git repository

Tags: git

Can we tag a single folder from a git repository?

We have a git repository with different folders, we don't want to tag the entire repository. We just want to tag a single folder from that git repository.

Is that possible or better to have different repositories instead of having a single repository?

Comment: In my experience it is better to have different repositories.  You can add a .gitignore file that will tell git to ignore stuff, so you could add lines to the .gitignore for each other folder in your repository, but I imagine things being easier if you just put the git repository in the single folder you are interested in tracking.

Comment: ElpieKay's answer is correct ... and not useful to you because you weren't interested in *Git* but rather in Git*Hub*. This is why formulating good questions is important! :-)

Comment: sorry ,that i have mentioned github. i have used github to check that tag has been created or not. I have created the tag , now i want to clone the tag only not the entire repository. is there a way to clone that single tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git tag for a subfolder of a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796735/git-tag-for-a-subfolder-of-a-repository)

Answer (score 1):

**No you cannot associate a tag to a folders inside a git repository**

This because each tag is associated to a particular commit.

So each commit refers to the whole repository which includes both folders.

If each of your folders are unrelated to each others, yes you should definitely have two separated repositories.

Let's imagine this timeline:

```
 * 4bde21c 5m ago, Fix spelling (master)
 * 4bde21c 10h ago, Fix foo (v1.0-foo)
 * 7cdeba1 3 days ago, Fix bar (v1.0-bar)
 * 3cd4aa1 10 days ago, Create bar
 * 21a57d2 1 month ago, Create foo
```

The tags `v1.0-foo` and `v1.0-bar` are just references to commits:

```
 v1.0-foo -> 4bde21c
 v1.0-bar -> 7cdeba1
```

So how would you consider the version of the `bar` repository at tag `v1.0-foo`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want it, so I just give some hints.

A folder with tracked files in a Git repository has its own revision, stored as a tree object. The object records the names of its files and subfolders and their own object hashes. But the object does not store its own path, which is stored in the tree object of its parent folder. If it's the root folder of the repository, its path is not stored at all. Because it could be any name when it is cloned or initialized.

Say the folder's path in the repository is `./foo`. You can run `git ls-tree <commit> -- foo` or `git rev-parse <commit>:foo` to see the tree hash of `foo`. You can tag it by `git tag <tagname> <tree_hash>`, or without knowing its hash by `git tag <tagname> <commit>:foo`.

With the tag, you can push or fetch the involved objects, or extract the actual files and subfolders, or manipulate them with plumbing commands.

As we can use `<commit>:<path>` to describe the path and contents of a folder, you don't have to create an extra tag if you know the commit and path.

Comment: I have executed below commands to tag a single folder from git repository. 1)git ls-tree HEAD 2) git tag <<tagname>> <<treehash>> 3) git push origin --tags . tag has been created , but when i click the tag on github , it is displaying error page. expecting to display that folder contents page. Can i get any help on this?

Comment: @AnRedd I'm afraid Github doesn't support to display a tree object. It's quite rare to tag a non-commit object. The only case I know is to tag a blob of GPG public key, which is used to validate a signed commit or tag.