# Cannot access script base class 'org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript'

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

When I create an empty project with Gradle Kotlin DSL, even without any modifications, it would prompt `Cannot access script base class 'org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies` The project can run, but the syntax highlighting and autocompletion for `build.gradle.kts` don't work.

#### What I've tried

- https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1308

  - Changing gradle executable to `gradle-kotlin-dsl-5.2-20190122225509+0000-all.zip`
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38296

  - Remove empty SDKs in Project structure dialog
  - Invalidate caches and restart
- Reinstalling Java 11 `brew install java11`
- Switching to official oracle JDK 15 ​`brew install oracle-jdk`
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41141

  - Re-adding SDKs in the SDK menu
  - Adding `/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib` to Kotlin SDK's classpath
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245027

  - Deleting the cache folder manually

[image]

#### System

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-203.6682.168, built on December 29, 2020
Licensed to Hykilpikonna Gui
Subscription is active until November 28, 2021.
For educational use only.
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.63 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1998M
Cores: 6
Registry: debugger.watches.in.variables=false, js.debugger.webconsole=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: CMD Support, Rider UI Theme Pack, Statistic, com.alayouni.ansiHighlight, com.intellij.ideolog, net.vektah.codeglance, String Manipulation, com.alibaba.p3c.smartfox, wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin, com.demonwav.minecraft-dev, lermitage.intellij.extra.icons, com.github.masahirosuzuka.PhoneGapIntelliJPlugin, Dart, io.flutter, deno, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.cybrosis.catdea, siosio.kodkod, izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets, org.jetbrains.plugins.ruby, Pythonid, org.jetbrains.plugins.vue, tv.twelvetone.intellij.plugins.intellivue, ru.meanmail.plugin.requirements
```

Comment: Does it help to delete IDEA caches _manually_ as described in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245027?

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov Sorry it didn't help. I tried invalidating caches and deleting the folder manually. After it indexed for a few minutes, the issue still exists. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: It could also help to remove all Gradle caches (/home/.gradle)

Comment: Please follow this issue, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-17923
Check Project Structure JDK

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Answer credit to [@AlexeyBelkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992380/alexey-belkov) - Answered here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-893

The syntax highlighting feature worked after:

1. Delete `~/.gradle/caches`
2. Delete `~/Library/Application\ Support/Library/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3` (or `~/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3` for ubuntu/linux users)
3. Delete `<project dir>/.gradle`
4. Delete `<project dir>/.idea`
5. Start IDEA and reimport the project.

Comment: It seems deleting C:\Users\<you>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.1\caches fixes the issue.

Comment: After doing this something improved, maybe, but I still had all KTS files "red". 
For Android Studio the solution was:
 I went to:
File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> "JDK Location" textbox: replace default "Embedded JDK" with a path to the separately downloaded Open JDK 11 resolved the issue.
More info: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41141

Comment: All I had to do was update the JDK as described by @yvolk above. The other suggestions (though generally helpful in these kinds of situations) wasn't the issue here.

Comment: For AndroidStudioPreview2021.1 deleting  ~/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudioPreview2021.1/caches worked

Comment: I like your (currently deleted) [suggestion for commit count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73095840/6309). Don't forget to add, [since Git 2.34](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48028196/6309), the option `--unsorted-input`, for an even faster result.

Comment: @VonC I'm sorry, I deleted that answer because it didn't actually work... Even though it did run faster, it returned 1 instead of the actual number of commits

Comment: @Hykilpikonna OK. What version of Git were you using?

Comment: @VonC I'm using the latest stable release 2.37.1. Also, it doesn't seem to recognize the `--unsorted-input` option. After some digging, it seems that `--unsorted-input` is added in `2.34.0-rc1` but later removed in the stable release of `2.34.0` (See [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.34.0-rc1/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt))

Comment: True: [commit a7df4f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7df4f52affe49f6b06246b9398e99e1937f9efc). Too bad! (`git log -S "unsorted-input" -- **.c`)

Comment: correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72912179/2297550

Answer (score 18):

In my case (the OS is Windows 10) it was enough to:

1. Delete `C:\Users\<you>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.1\caches`
2. Restart IntelliJ IDEA.
3. Click "Load Script Configurations" when it appears after re-indexing.

Thanks @MichaelBöckling for a hint!

Comment: Wow this solved my issue, also had to set the JDK in Project Structure dialog

Answer (score 16):

1. Close the Android Studio. (Mine was version 2021.2).
2. Delete jdk.table.xml from Android studio's [config folder](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#file_location) .
3. Open Android Studio and configure JDK in Gradle Settings (Project
   Structure -> SDK Location -> Gradle Settings).

Found the solution from [JetBrain's issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-17774/Gradle-Kotlin-DSL-MISSINGDEPENDENCYSUPERCLASS-errors-in-IDE#focus=Comments-27-5743835.0-0).

Comment: This should be marked as answer, deleting cache solves the problem only temporary.

Comment: yes, this is correct -- the config folder needs cleaning and other answers don't mention that

Comment: after everything with deleting caches etc. failed,
simply renaming `jdk.table.xml` helped
(note: I didn't delete <project dir>/.idea for some reason)

Comment: Thanks! I just add some additional info about path: {config_path}/options/jdk.table.xml

Comment: Also: item #3 setting is no longer there (or am I missing something?) but for me choosing JDK for Gradle in General IDE's settings (settings -> Build & Execution -> Gradle) to something other and then back to what you need (e.g. to jdk 1.8 and then to jdk 11) did the trick

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question: OP is asking for IntteliJ Idea, not Android studio.

Answer (score 13):

Mac OS:

1. File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> click on Gradle Settings
2. Modify the Gradle JDK
3. File -> Invalidate Caches...

[image]

[image]

Comment: This one worked for me on Windows! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Worked like a charme!

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me after I'd deleted:

```
Delete <project dir>/.gradle
Delete <project dir>/.idea
```

Answer (score 4):

## Guided Cache Recovery (IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3+)

IntelliJ IDEA versions from 2021.3 and on (as of writing, available from JetBrain's Early Access Program, or EAP) has a featured called "Guided Cache Recovery" (`File`, `Run Guided Cache Recovery...`). While I can't find any documentation yet about this feature, it appears to give the user the ability to apply diagnostic/recovery steps, one at a time, to fixing any cache issues.

For me, the problem reported by the OP was resolved at step 2: "Rescan Project Indexes".

The really cool thing about this is that, not only did it fix my problem, but IntelliJ then created an issue report with details about the problem found, and gave me the option of submitting this report to JetBrains via the crash reporter. This tells me that JetBrains appears to be serious about fixing these issues for users, *and* about resolving their root causes.

## Permissions Issues in .idea, .gradle, or gradle

Another possible problem is permissions issues in one of the `.idea`, `.gradle`, or `gradle` directories. For example, running a rootfull docker container, mounting the project as a volume (for example, to run a tool like Qodana) could cause some files to become owned by `root` unless the appropriate Docker options are used. If this issue is noticed, reset permissions with `chmod` and `chown` and then sync again in IDEA.

Answer (score 3):

I set the project SDK to Kotlin under `Project Settings > Modules`. I also set the SDK in `Plaftorm Settings > SDKs` although I don't know if that's required. And just in case I restarted IntelliJ with `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart ...`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For IntelliJ 2021.1, I had to delete the caches folder at:
`~/Libary/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/caches`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to set the Java version in IntelliJ -> Settings -> Build -> Gradle to 1.8 to match the projects Java version

Answer (score 2):

In my case updating Kotlin version manually in inteliJ worked.

You can do it in: `Settings` -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `Kotlin`

[image: InteilJ settings]

Answer (score 1):

For me, solution was to install a separate JDK version (I installed **Temurin JDK 17**). I then simply set it to `JAVA_HOME` and used it in the AS and the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest IntelliJ/Android Studio versions they've added a new action called "Repair IDE".
By running that, it incrementally does more steps that could potentially fix such issues for you.
I was experiencing this issue for example, and after clicking the automatic actions 3 times, where it reopened my project, this was fixed.
I would really recommend you try out that action next time you feel like your IDE is in an odd state.

Answer (score 1):

i use community version intellij idea 2023.2.3
when generate project gradle-kotlin and language kotlin from https://start.spring.io/ get error like above
to resolve it change gradle to latest version 8.4 and
kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.10"
kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.10"
that is latest

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the Kotlin SDK and updating your Gradle project.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f38N4.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXVWp.png

Answer (score -1):

You need to delete de cache at

> ~/.gradle/caches

But an easier way is to do it from IDE, under file menu
you will find "**Invalidate Caches**" option

Hope it works for you

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, gradle caches are not removed by IDE, including this Invalidate&Restart menu item.

Comment: does not work..

Answer (score -1):

[My solution is as shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4RLz.png)

I tried but
The method below didn't work.
use in android studio android ver AndroidStudio2022.1

1. remove ~/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2022.1/caches
2. remove /.gradle/caches

Comment: does not work...

Answer (score -3):

In my case, I had to install the previous IDE version (2021.1.3).

Comment: What version was that?

Comment: The version is 2021.1.3.

Comment: In addition. Sometimes, projects may be "broken" after automatic updates. So, I`m trying to install IDEs manually.