# Gradle build fails after deleting caches

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I was trying to run my project in Android Studio but I've got an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645510/cannot-access-script-base-class-org-gradle-kotlin-dsl-kotlinbuildscript) and the solution was to delete the caches folder from .gradle.

After deleting the cahces folder, I get this error when I build my project.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\user1\.gradle\caches\jars-9\e5fbce9be10133b9388133408d88c9b9\init.jar.
> org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\user1\.gradle\caches\jars-9\e5fbce9be10133b9388133408d88c9b9\init.jar.
```

I tried invalidating caches but it didn't work either.