# Android Studio - Cannot access script base class 'org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've been trying to update my android studio project build.gradle(app) from Groovy to Kotlin.  I have created a `build.gradle.kts` file and added a few lines to it:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        }

    dependencies {
        Dependencies.playServicesGMS
        Dependencies.firebaseCrashlyticsGradle
        Dependencies.hiltGradlePlugin
        }
}

apply (plugin = "com.android.application")
apply (plugin = "com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin")
apply (plugin = "com.android.application")
apply (plugin = "com.google.gms.google-services")
apply (plugin = "com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
apply (plugin = "kotlin-android")
apply (plugin = "kotlin-parcelize")
apply (plugin = "kotlin-kapt")
apply (plugin = "dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
```

However I'm getting errors, the code looks like this:
[image]

This isn't the first `gradle.kts` file I've created, I have already converted the project `build.gradle` to `build.gradle.kts` and coverted the code without encountering this issue.

I have followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645510/cannot-access-script-base-class-org-gradle-kotlin-dsl-kotlinbuildscript), I don't know if it's applicable as I already have a kotlin gradle file successfully converted.

If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it as I've spent a lot time on this and I'm not sure what to do next, plus, it shouldn't be this bloody difficult!!

Thank you

Comment: "script configuration wasn't received" is an IDE error message. Sometimes it gets a bit confused when you make major changes to the build. Try re-linking the IDE project with Gradle/deleting caches/restarting the IDE. Also, at any time you can simply run `./gradlew` from a terminal to obtain feedback on whether your build script _really_ works, as opposed to being an IDE configuration error.

Comment: Thank you Simon for your reply.  I've ran gradle in terminal and it isn't complaining.  I've restarted Android Studio, clearing caches but it doesn't work.  I appreciate your help thus far but if you have any instructions on how to sort this with Android Studio, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'd keep going clearing things until it treats it as a fresh project. You can try "unlink Gradle project" and re-link it. You can delete the `.idea` folder, the `build` folders and the `.gradle` folder. The IDE also has repair options.

Comment: Thanks Simon, yeah I've run the repair options, they don't work, I've deleted the .idea folder also, unfortunately, that doesn't work either.  I've also tried this suggested answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645510/cannot-access-script-base-class-org-gradle-kotlin-dsl-kotlinbuildscript#:~:text=Close%20the%20Android%20Studio.%20(Mine%20was but unfortunately I cannot locate my config folder as it isn't located at the path stated in the docs

Comment: The last refuge is always changing the base folder name and re-opening that. Then it will have to treat as a fresh project. Maybe it is also possible you don't have the Kotlin plugin installed in Android Studio, which I assume is needed