# git : a file in the history without commits on it, how to explain it?

Tags: git, svn, git-rewrite-history

I am migrating many svn repositories to many other git repositories. Those svn repos have more than 113000 commits.
I end up with very large git repos and I like to shrink them.

I have used a [script](http://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/) to find out the largest objects. These objects are not in any branches anymore and I wanted to know to which commit they where related.
I could not find any ???

I used the command

```
git log --pretty=oneline --branches -- my_big_file_full_path
```

But nothing was returned.
Can someone explain me why this file has no associated commits ?
If that is really the case how to remove all the files that are not linked to any commits ?

PS : the migration process is quite heavy and I am using [bfg](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) (which is fantastic) to remove some known unused folders.

Comment: "*I have used a script to find out the largest objects.*" There's more than 1 script in the blog post that you linked to, can you please edit into your question **the exact code** that you used?

Comment: @Cupcake: what do you mean? I only see one script there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the answer in another stackoverflow question [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob)
using the shell script allowed me to find the commit that modified the big file.

Answer (score 1):

Did you clean the repository after using The BFG? As mentiond in the "Usage" section on the [BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) site you should use

```
$ cd some-big-repo.git
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

to get rid of objects in the repositories that are not part of any commit.

Comment: Thank a lot for that suggestion but this does not resolve my problem. Indeed it reduced the size of my repository but the "my_big_file_full_path" is still present and I still not related to any commit. I wish I knew why?

Comment: It actually was just a suggestion. Would have posted it as a comment, but my rep score wouldn't allow for that. What you describe sounds like a dangling commit to me, and you get rid of these with the commands mentioned. What does git fsck --full tell you?

Comment: the git fsck seems to be ok here what I have got

git fsck --full 
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (144252/144252), done.
But I still got most of the biggest objects not related to any commit.

Comment: Then you have e.g. tags referencing some tree in which your big file is still referenced. What does git log --pretty=oneline --all -- my_big_file_full_path tell you?

Comment: Dear Daniel, unfortunatly this command give no result at all. Just like the first one I used.