# Git command to discover which version of a file I currently have?

Tags: git

This comes up a few times around the office and I don't have an answer when it does. Let's say you distribute your source code as a binary. A few years later, someone finds a bug in file system/foo.cpp. They give me their original foo.cpp and the updated version of it that has the bug fix. The problem is, foo.cpp has had 600 total revisions, and you don't know which revision they had originally modified.

Is there a way to use the original foo.cpp provided by the bug fixes to discover which exact SHA1 tree revision had the first instance of that original foo.cpp? In other words, is there a git utility or helper script to search every system/foo.cpp revision comparing it to the submitted foo.cpp to find which revision they modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`git hash-object`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object) to compute the blob hash of a file, i.e. the identifier of the file’s content.

With that blob hash, you can do something as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob) to find out which commits contain that blob.