# How to find the commit having only a snapshot of the repo

Tags: git

I have a full repo, with all commit history, `repo`

I also have a snapshot of the repo, made sometime in the past. Let's call it `snapshot`. The snapshot is based on the version of the repo as taken in the past, with some additions/changes.

If I check the differences:

```
$ diff -wqr repo/ snapshot/  | grep -c differ
538
$ diff -wqr repo/ snapshot/  | grep -cv differ
9
```

So, I am positive that not that many changes have been made to the master repo: I am simply looking at the wrong repo commit. But which one is the commit were the snapshot was taken?

There are so many differences that I do not know where to start. I know nothing about the repo, so I am clueless of when the snapshot was taken. There is no date information which can point me to a certain period, no `VERSION` file, nothing ...

What comes to my mind is to take one of the files in the snapshot which differ from the repo, and run a command to see in which commit that file appears verbatim. With some luck, I will get something like:

```
$ list-commits.sh snapshot/xxx/my-file.py repo
File snapshot/xxx/my-file.py appears verbatim in following commits:
b77ee66
74f6d4f
...
```

(It could also be that I am by chance chosing one of the files that really changed in the snapshot: in that case I will get no commit list, and I will try another file)

This would limit the commits that I need to investigate. Is there a method of doing this with plain git commands?

Comment: "Snapshot* is usually used as a synonym of "revision" and "commit". What meaning does it have, in your question?

Comment: You can use the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob) combined with `git hash-object` to do what you want (find commits that contain a specific file).

Comment: @Jubobs: just a version the repo, without the history (no `.git` directory).

Comment: Do you have to compare multiple branches? If not, comparing the master branches can be done by adding a remote and using `git log --left-right repo/master...snapshot/master`

Comment: @jeremytwfortune: as mentioned in the question: the *snapshot* has no history information **at all**. No branches, no commits, no tags, no nothing, just the working dir.