# Which git commit/branch contains this blob?

Tags: git

I am using this script to compute the n largest blops in my repository:

https://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/

An example of the output:

```
54016,13273,0ef462bf57e8c036b00b52d6cc0fd91b2fc2a827 Data/Db.MDF
30976,8734,3e162c8313995980c8d6fc434c06789373364a47 Tools/connector.dll
```

The two SHAs above are SHAs for the blops. Now I would like to locate the commit/branch that contains those blops. I first tried:

```
$ git branch -a --contains 3e162c8313995980c8d6fc434c06789373364a47
error: object 3e162c8313995980c8d6fc434c06789373364a47 is a blob, not a commit
```

As the message says above the SHA is for a blob not a commit. This leads me to: [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob)

I have created the two scripts from the above post and added those to the root of my repository. But when I run them nothing gets outputted:

```
MINGW64 /c/tmp/MyRepo (master)
$ ./blop-to-commit.sh 3e162c8313995980c8d6fc434c06789373364a47

MINGW64 /c/tmp/MyRepo (master)
```

Also tried to run it on a local bare clone of the repository:

```
MINGW64 /c/tmp/MyRepo.bare (BARE:master)
$ ./blop-to-commit.sh 3e162c8313995980c8d6fc434c06789373364a47

MINGW64 /c/tmp/MyRepo.bare (BARE:master)
```

Any ideas why I don't get the commit/branch that contained that blop at some point in history?

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

Seems I just had to add the --all option to the git log command:

```
shift
git log --all "$@" --pretty=format:'%T %h %s' \
| while read tree commit subject ; do
    if git ls-tree -r $tree | grep -q "$obj_name" ; then
        echo $commit "$subject"
    fi
done
```

As suggested below:

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (100278/100278), done.
Checking connectivity: 100342, done.
dangling commit 3f8cd0a581ec694e7371f7e4183e1cad8fa87647
dangling commit d5c0f41337ae1ef8e5cfbfd4f70077c36d231cf1
dangling commit b01831f4e6679ef2696a83e6dbaa04eaf6748f85
dangling commit 82b32531c23202d123f693bba64b040b3247636b
dangling commit 4fa8ce87c268a7ddb7c4e72d6810f70e197d5812
dangling commit 3ce38a0b8e5dbb7424a88359bbe0d9130ced34dc
```

I then did:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

But I still don't see corresponding commits for the blobs originally listed.

Comment: Try running `git fsck` to see if the blob is not a dangling object

Answer (score 0):

Because you already have both the hash of the blob *and* the path a very performant method to discover the SHA1 of the commit that introduced the file can discovered by using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob/32611564#32611564). Then, as you tried before you can use `git branch -a --contains <sha1>` to find the branches that contain the commit.

Answer (score -1):

You can run this script to get the size of your files (much simplier):

```
git ls-tree --full-tree -r --long HEAD | sort -rnk4
```

---

#### How to find where is the SHA-1 is in?

***Note:*** once you add file to git (not commit but adding), git pack and store it. The packing generate the SHA-1 of the file.  This means that if later no you   **did not** commit the file but you still have the SHA-1 stored in your `.git` folder even if its not part of any commit tree.

Assuming that you did commit the object into branch here is how to find out in which branches its in:

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

You can also pass tags instead of branch

```
git tags--contains <commit>
```

---

#### What do to if not commit is not in any branch/tags?

It simply means that the SHA-1 is not in any commit (as explained above).

run fsck to find out ifs its a dangling object or clean your repo before executing the size calculation.

```
# clean repo
git fsck --full --prune=now
```

Comment: I have updated my post. I did try the git branch -a --contains <sha> but as can be read from the message it does not accept blob sha's. Notice I am looking for commits for blobs back in time that are not necessarily on the tip of any branches.