# Big file removed from history isn't removed from remote

Tags: git, github

I'm migrating a repo from server to another server but it contains too big file for the new server. The file was not needed so I removed it with filter-branch:
`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -f --ignore-unmatch "path\to\big.file"' --prune-empty  --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`
Combined with `git reflog expire --expire=now --all` and `git gc --prune=now --aggressive`

History changed (on all subsequent brances) and the file is not shown on log. Then I `git push --all --force` to old server. Problem is that the object still exists on server. If I make a new clone it is there, shown with this command:
`git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | sed -n 's/^blob //p' | sort --numeric-sort --key=2 | cut -c 1-12,41- | $(command -v gnumfmt || echo numfmt) --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest > ObjectSizes.txt`

When finding which commit has the object with this:
`git log --all --pretty=format:%H -- <path> | xargs -I% sh -c "git ls-tree % -- <path> | grep -q <hash> && echo %"`
it gives one hash. But that commit is not on any branch anymore, by `git branch -a --contains <sha1>`. The hash is the original commit with the big file which now is rewritten on all the branches.

How the object could be removed from server?

Background: I need the object to be removed from old server, and not just push to new server, because I need to use external migration tool to copy also pull requests etc.

Sources for commands:
[Suddenly added some large files to git VCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930101/suddenly-added-some-large-files-to-git-vcs)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32611564
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61090582

Comment: You say "if I make a new clone". How do you make a new clone? `git clone origrepo clonedrepo` could explain your observation, because it just hardlinks the entire object database.

Comment: I cloned from remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found, from the clone, with `git for-each-ref --contains <sha1>` (instead of branch -a) that the big file is referenced by multiple tags. So I realized that rewritten tags had not been updated to remote. When I did it with `git push --tags --force`, the problem was solved.

So to everybody else, remember to force push also tags if you have rewritten history.