# git verify pack and only returning blob objects

Tags: git

I am using this script from [here](https://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/) to list large blobs in my Git repository:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x 

# Shows you the largest objects in your repo's pack file.
# Written for osx.
#
# @see https://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/
# @author Antony Stubbs

# set the internal field spereator to line break, so that we can iterate easily over the verify-pack output
IFS=$'\n';

# list all objects including their size, sort by size, take top 10
objects=`git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | grep -v chain | sort -k3nr | head`

echo "All sizes are in kB's. The pack column is the size of the object, compressed, inside the pack file."

output="size,pack,SHA,location"
for y in $objects
do
    # extract the size in bytes
    size=$((`echo $y | cut -f 5 -d ' '`/1024))
    # extract the compressed size in bytes
    compressedSize=$((`echo $y | cut -f 6 -d ' '`/1024))
    # extract the SHA
    sha=`echo $y | cut -f 1 -d ' '`
    # find the objects location in the repository tree
    other=`git rev-list --all --objects | grep $sha`
    #lineBreak=`echo -e "\n"`
    output="${output}\n${size},${compressedSize},${other}"
done

echo -e $output | column -t -s ', '
```

I am a little puzzled about this line:

```
objects=`git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | grep -v chain | sort -k3nr | head`
```

Why do a `grep -v chain` (where -v is invert match)? As a result you would both get **commit**, **blob** and **tree** objects. But are the binaries not always stored in a **blob** object? Meaning that for locating large binaries you should simply do: **grep blob** instead?

I don't see the purpose of including **tree** and **commit** objects in the result set.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48027778/6309

Answer (score 0):

The `grep -v chain` tosses out lines like these:

```
chain length = 1: 44 objects
chain length = 2: 30 objects
chain length = 3: 15 objects
chain length = 4: 11 objects
```

which, indeed, seems a bit pointless since their numeric value for field 3 (`-k3nr`) will be the numeric value of the string "=", i.e., zero.

> But are the binaries not always stored in a **blob** object? Meaning that for locating large binaries you should simply do: **grep blob** instead?

Sure.  Or leave out all `grep`s and run it on everything, including the final line(s) of the form:

```
.git/objects/pack/pack-6a0a97d0239b29f4fef82f52b326317cd0cdd94f.pack: ok
```

It's not likely that a tree or commit or tag object will make the top ten, and if it does, it might be interesting to see.