# How to find file revision or commit from git repository by a file hash?

Tags: git, hash

I have a git diff output that contains lines like this: `index 0056c73..92c6cbd 100644` for each file.  I know which repository it comes from, but unfortunately have no idea *which revision of the repository* it is diffing against.

How do I find the commit of the repository that the diff is against?

Alternately, how do I find the exact commit of each file that the pre-image hashes in the diff correspond to?  (i.e. which version of a file has the `0056c73` hash in the example above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the path of the file, you can start displaying all the commits for said path:

```
git log --all --pretty=format:%H <path>
```

If `0056c73` is a blob SHA1 for that file, a [`git ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) will print all entries SHA1, and you can grep the one you are after.

"[Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32611564/6309)" proposes this one-liner from [**aragaer**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390363/aragaer):

```
git log --all --pretty=format:%H <path> | xargs -n1 -I% sh -c "git ls-tree % <path> | grep -q <hash> && echo %"
```

(replace `<hash>` with `0056c73`)

As I mentioned in "[Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48027778/6309)", with Git 2.16+ (Dec. 2017), you can use:

- `git describe`
- [`git log  --oneline --find-object(=...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48590251/6309)

Comment: Note this looks by blob hash as returned by `git hash-object` or `sha1("blob " + filesize + "\0" + content)`, and not regular sha1sum of the file content.  That's indeed the hashes uses in `index 0056c73..92c6cbd` diif headers.  It just surprised me as I had actual file contents and wanted to find commit...

Comment: `git log --find-object=<blob>` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As elaborated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48027778/239657, since Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), you can simply run `git describe 0056c73`.
Example on another repo:

```
$ git show d69fe27cf937398fa2bf6813674a3975bfe56e89 | grep e1cfe5
index 6e180f8221..e1cfe56bf6 100755
$ git describe e1cfe56bf6
1.1.0.Beta2-7645-gd69fe27cf9:adapters/oidc/js/src/main/resources/keycloak.js
$ git describe e1cfe56bf6 --abbrev=40
1.1.0.Beta2-7645-gd69fe27cf937398fa2bf6813674a3975bfe56e89:adapters/oidc/js/src/main/resources/keycloak.js
```

You can play with `git describe` flags to tweak the friendly lookup of close tags vs just showing the commit hash...

Comment: Good point. I have edited my answer to reflect that, since the link you mention... is an answer I wrote.