# How to find commits with file not present in working tree

Tags: git

I have file path and blob name of a file that is not in working tree. How can I find in which commits this file present?

**EDIT:**

I can cat file with `git cat-file -p <blob>` but nor `log -S`, nor `log <path>` nor `bisect` give me any results.

It may happen that this file in different branch or even in some fetched but not checked out branch

Comment: If the file used to be present and it was removed at some point you can use [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) to find out the commit that removed it.

Comment: This answer might be what you need (finding all commits which contain that blob): https://stackoverflow.com/a/223890/1406321 However you will need to add `--all` to the fourth line of the shell script (starting with `git log`), as otherwise only the history of HEAD is being searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked, finding which commits have a particular blob at a particular path, git doesn't have a pushbutton for it, but it's pretty easy to generate anything you want.

```
git log --all --reflog --format='%H:path/to/it %H' \
| git cat-file --batch-check='%(rest) %(objectname)' \
| awk '$2==myblob{print $1}' myblob=`git rev-parse mycommit:path/to/it` \
| git log --no-walk --stdin --oneline
```

and for just eyeballing it just the first two lines might be enough.

Comment: I couldn't understand how this do the thing, but it do.

Comment: Needs more explanation. Should I be substituting `mycommit` for something? I get `fatal: invalid object name 'mycommit'`. If I try to substitute `mycommit` for `HEAD` or `main`, I get errors like `fatal: path 'foobar' does not exist in 'main'`.

Answer (score 3):

## Git Log

From here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Searching

```
git log -S "some content in that file"
```

Search for a filename:

```
git log --follow -- my_file_name.txt
```

## Git Bisect

```
git bisect start HEAD <initial_commit>
git bisect run [[ -e my_file_name.txt ]]
```

Comment: No result. It may happen that Im on different branch now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git log path/to/file` to show each commit that modified the file, including the one that removed it.

Comment: I have got "unknown revision or path not in the working tree"

Answer (score 1):

[`git log --diff-filter=RD`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203)

Select only files that are Renamed or Deleted.