# How to apply patch without knowing the original version the diff file comes from?

Tags: git, blender, patch

I'm trying to apply a patch file (1) I found online to Blender (2). However, with so many versions in the official repository I'm not sure which version the patch should be applied to.

I checked out several earlier versions of Blender and tried

```
patch -p1 < ../blender-custom-nodes/patch/compositor_nodes.diff
```

but all of them results in some rejects. Is there any easy way to tell which version the patch should be applied to?

(1) https://github.com/bitsawer/blender-custom-nodes
(2) https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/branches/master/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... Is there any easy way to tell which version the patch should be applied to?

Only if the patch contains an `index` line.  (Even then, it's not necessarily *easy*, and there may be many revisions to which the patch might apply.)  In this case, [that patch](https://github.com/bitsawer/blender-custom-nodes/blob/master/patch/compositor_nodes.diff) does have such a line:

```
diff --git a/extern/CMakeLists.txt b/extern/CMakeLists.txt
index 91919ad..fed9e0c 100644
--- a/extern/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/extern/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -37,6 +37,7 @@ if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
[snip]
```

The `index` line in a Git diff provides the old and new blob hash IDs.  This means the version of `CMakeLists.txt` to which the patch applies is a blob whose abbreviated hash ID is `91919ad`.  If this hash ID is not uniquely some particular blob, one is in trouble; cloning the repository as it is today, I find:

```
$ git rev-parse 91919ad
91919adb4a289234062a27bed0276cb098d1e5d5
```

so we can use the answers from [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/223678/1256452)

Rather than the fancy perl script, I went with VonC's answer:

```
$ git log --oneline --find-object=91919adb4a289234062a27bed0276cb098d1e5d5
e0597baed57 Remove Carve boolean
e8daf2e3ea1 CMake: cleanup
```

Note that we could use the abbreviated hash here since it's still unique:

```
$ git log --oneline --find-object=91919ad
e0597baed57 Remove Carve boolean
e8daf2e3ea1 CMake: cleanup
```

It's best to keep the full hash ID around, though, as eventually, the shortened hash may become non-unique and only a longer hash will serve.  (The full hash will always work, as there's nothing longer than the full hash.)

Note that there are many commits "between" these two:

```
$ git rev-list --count e8daf2e3ea1..e0597baed57
752
```

*All* of those commits (except the last one) *share* that one version of `extern/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
$ git show e8daf2e3ea1 -- extern/CMakeLists.txt
commit e8daf2e3ea17c2e9569e6fc9b49879c74d9a8c22
Author: Campbell Barton [snip]

diff --git a/extern/CMakeLists.txt b/extern/CMakeLists.txt
index f7e98525b8b..91919adb4a2 100644
--- a/extern/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/extern/CMakeLists.txt
[snip]
```

This commit is the start of the 751 commits that contain that version of that file.  Meanwhile:

```
$ git show e0597baed57 -- extern/CMakeLists.txt
commit e0597baed57fa7a9dfaf6dff6d0fa120784d21ea
Author: Sergey Sharybin [snip]

diff --git a/extern/CMakeLists.txt b/extern/CMakeLists.txt
index 91919adb4a2..2e8589ffd17 100644
--- a/extern/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/extern/CMakeLists.txt
```

This is the first commit that *stops* using that version of `extern/CMakeLists.txt` (after which no other master-branch version uses it).

Comment: "Rather than the fancy perl script, I went with VonC's answer:" Warning, my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48590251/6309), with its `git log --oneline --find-object=v2.0.0:Makefile`, is for Git 2.17 or more.

Comment: Thanks! So given each file were changed versus a different commit, is there any way to checkout just one version along the branch so I can apply the patch to all files in a single line?

Comment: @matohak: no, but that does not make sense anyway. Consider this rather weak analogy: someone says that if you wear a red hat on Tuesday, or a blue shoe on Friday, you can get into some particular club. Wearing a red hat *and* a blue shoe together on Wednesday or Thursday is not a winning combination. If you have patch A for version A, patch B for version B, and patch C for version C, it doesn't follow that applying all three patches to any one version will produce something that works. This, of course, is the point of *commits* rather than patches: a commit is [continued]

Comment: ... a commit is a single version, in which *every* file is consistent with *every other* file. If someone sends a patch, instead of a commit, they should tell you which commit the patch applies to, rather than making you guess. That patch will then apply to all the files from that particular commit.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. If they didn't tell me which commit the patch applies to, how can I find out? Does that mean I have to guess?

Comment: Apparently so. I did not look over the linked repository closely; perhaps there is some clue in there?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to apply the patch using blender v2.79 (8ef39d5c882896bd75e0d4d17fb3e3d4710fc768).