# Any way to recover the git commits (or the full repo) from `index` and `objects`?

Tags: git

I had a local git repo (not pushed anywhere remotely) and due to a series of failures, most of the files in the .git folder were lost, except the `index` file and the `objects` folder which has 149 subfolders, each of two letters, but no "pack" or "info" subfolders. I'm unsure if these are unaffected, but it seems previouosly committed content is intact, see below. I do have the latest source files outside the .git folder.

I first did a `git init`. Trying `git cat-file -p <filehash>` where `<filehash>` is a file name in one of the subfolders in `objects` does show previously committed file content, so it looks like the stuff is there! I then did a `git fsck` and `git log <dangling commit hash>` which recognizes some of the commits (!) but at the end says `Failed to traverse parents of commit <hash>`.

Is there a way to recover my commits, even if partially, without painstaking manual labor? I haven't found a clear step by step guide that isn't assuming git knowledge. I'd very much appreciate one. I just want to be able to revert to some older commits (even if I lose the commits comments).

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in B:/node/api/.git/

$ find .git/objects/ -type f |sed 's:\.git/objects/::; s:/::'| wc -l
210

$ find .git/objects/ -type f |sed 's:\.git/objects/::; s:/::'| head
00130817b1f87593f3425d7b2a0c944950c8b43c
00332e118c6b2a8262ed9a15755e164027d7128a
0273ce793844195ffac500c4e4eda7e8472bf2e1
03815dddd192af3da7f8612827137b64589ca98c
041336afc8226581897c3c880733001f2632ecd8
046b4eb28ac3d3f8fe58bdf5318e002758cdb7d2
04d0004715f30b0ce62afb8c9d72d1186b1a109f
05210208754e117efb216bec37a6b57b827cb9e0
06833614f7b9fefa6aac0d703bb52b0e3dffed9e
07c833c146786495c3e43cd4682b84c8ae24c5ff

$ git cat-file -p 00130817b1f87593f3425d7b2a0c944950c8b43c
040000 tree 0273ce793844195ffac500c4e4eda7e8472bf2e1    base
100644 blob ceafae85b5a7b58c30c67c25fb25679b7cb4e6b3    <filesnip1>.js
100644 blob bd464a4b21337d47b2a5d4da281527f977ccae59    <filesnip2>.js
100644 blob ac538bbe08b480cc1736b7ccde563462c666e136    <filesnip3>.js
100644 blob 50198635620a00083b49f65ccbabb5432f64b76c    <filesnip4>.js
100644 blob 08dc53aa1280c8d40fa8e7e611fd4a5985a1dbe4    <filesnip5>.js
100644 blob 04d0004715f30b0ce62afb8c9d72d1186b1a109f    <filesnip6>.js
100644 blob 78b0f4c9b9d5c9757a5c87b89845d4cfc89be45a    <filesnip7>.js
100644 blob e8bb79792e940c243c156af1b4ef7947a8b60843    <filesnip8>.js
100644 blob 3a195ba028c5b3bd5bc08a61ed16b7d4645f608f    <filesnip9>.js

$ git cat-file -p 78b0f4c9b9d5c9757a5c87b89845d4cfc89be45a
'use strict';
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const crypto = require("crypto");
...
...
<snip>
...
...
```

File content is intact. So the previously committed content seems it's all there! Can the commits themselves be recovered?

Here's the output of `git fsck --full` and `git log <dangling commit hash>`:

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
notice: No default references
error: 31395bd3c56cb9e0f4b6882826ac00c2df98b396: invalid sha1 pointer in cache-tree
missing blob 0a623d6bd10c64e268fa8b2c9f2265f15a5d1c49
missing blob 0f04d1005cec5fa6b954d5d7ae31f8f4fe89f5b1
missing blob 13a8aaebc96a76511a730bb9526243684f6eb4f0
missing blob 1a90cf5b56a5a67efb3a7c693fdb159d3b2333ef
dangling blob 212c4ba239ecdbd15c70c05b9336c32175dc8c5c
missing blob 28f6cd30ac098c14d03f32e7e74c2d90f0001b9d
dangling blob 2afa9b0a0057403671580afd16db135503e4d86c
dangling commit 2cb8f3bc3392c4287a1c014d1afc88183f564ba5
missing blob 2e8e889399cbba02a0665df6f6b04cba4d19970d
dangling commit 2d8a7f7b3bf4a437acd9fbe7904b51297d940154
missing blob 307c8a584c7c05d6f3f77945ef0f4f4deebb58da
missing blob 638a6d123efd95eaf3fabf2b6f81f15a3a70d17b
missing blob 67bceb41e2fd3301c30a47bf86de3f76a8d840b4
missing blob 72403d000b71f3d678432206745c52cd7c3e0bf9
missing blob 8d02eb842a03e66e4d942921db524b91aef2dd4a
dangling commit 8dfacc9d8d1530547ddf55b5e54796278cf5f9bf
missing blob 91b44d863eccff6483d1a7511878eeb5494a9404
missing blob afd6a13fda5798509d012b17117478902d7bbc92
missing blob b7f6f0306338eddf56e40c74e30d32dc5ba361a7
missing blob da48049b5d255e43ebb1281bd3d313e22200d000
missing blob de98c1d07b58b9ac3f99319092cfac0b7dbe4a5d
missing blob e65ecbc974e50872399851b0e270492ce8e4f78b
missing blob 15313550fc7153a6c2603bf687df8dde11ed451c
dangling commit 1ecf3a6eafc10c54da23d8da4b2b4439456a1ba9
missing blob 216b0dc693aac0934b7e7d67500b0c216dae60d4
missing blob 401f63a8a0cf1c37ac82d6663cabc13980f43d3c
missing blob 42359d7a307b1b206c1ba4bf4bedb5d0e87e8b81
missing blob 70374d79f8c53af2562e29691406c0aca12addf7
missing blob 7a9fe1056263a4ed262ec8c316eed51eabe467c0
dangling blob 84b1e93a4ccc6bb4d8f2ee038b902c507b76cbbf
missing blob 8f43ce81726561e0843e02ec02968586b424d73f
missing blob 92f3e3b2ab1b34cea7e98bce845ef07f7368f664
missing blob 9661ac713428efbad557d3ba3a62216b5bb7d226
missing blob 98450138737955b70aecf50cc7a28a1e540d411d
missing blob 983114632b6d8e5882b709fe6ba7ec1ac9a0f017
missing blob 9c138981e1437146a34d6b439fe9f20ccd311e4e
missing blob 9d35cccba009b99a9efecee76ae8358e825a37c4
missing blob b6b5be1995ac059924e59cfa5ea52d4f30ee3934
missing blob bca772ddcd6ff824e3c6151ae6af16bb7b725bad
dangling commit cdcb900c1ee7c13ec9f9170d9fd920a427042458
missing blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
missing blob e991eacc220822ac737ad17e38743e21cf3a8b93
missing blob f467ddd0ec8bb3dbc374990d5dea5173790e570a
missing blob f933a3defe31685010d9cea152053e65bed54d32
```

```
$ git log cdcb900c1ee7c13ec9f9170d9fd920a427042458
commit cdcb900c1ee7c13ec9f9170d9fd920a427042458
Author: norm
Date:   Sat Feb 16 20:35:09 2019 +0000

    added getActiveProfile, changed cmd, other changes and fixes

commit cac37842f103fc996b3fcc14c79b5f1290dd193a
Author: norm
Date:   Sat Feb 16 20:32:51 2019 +0000

    fix websocket connect to properly re-initialize when reconnecting; safe fetching of <snip> upon connection

commit cfef70660bf2588a036e42af71864cae9e4306f2
Author: norm
Date:   Sat Feb 16 20:31:41 2019 +0000

    show websocket error code on close, add colors and RandomInterval class to static properties

commit b8c46712337390b1b6951ddec22877bc544819a0
Author: norm
Date:   Sat Feb 16 20:30:29 2019 +0000

    export round8()

commit 7b56367e9c36c5e8184430c81c92eedac6997a55
Author: norm
Date:   Sat Feb 16 20:25:35 2019 +0000

    fix bug for 0 random shift which is supposed to use standard setInterval()
error: Could not read eb3e02f2e8077321e777262cecdaa8f30639e04a
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 55f6802879262fc5861c38e49078ce7f5648a116
```

Comment: You could point branches to those commits: `git branch some-branch cdcb900c1ee7c13ec9f9170d9fd920a427042458`, for example.

Comment: Dangling commit is usually not a problem. That just means that you have a commit which is no longer referred to by a branch.

However, "missing blob" is a severe issue. That means blob objects (ie. file contents) are missing in the git object data base (missing in `.git/objects`). I think recovering those "missing blobs" is impossible. That being said, partial recovery might be possible, but some files are missing, and will be unrecoverable.

Comment: @Alderath thanks for the info. I'm interested in recovering previous commits (since I do have the latest version of all source files which I'm not interested in recovering). To interpret your message: Is it that I can recover some commits but not others? Or is it that the first (oldest) broken commit with missing blobs will break all subsequent commits that had been made and hence I can recover only the commits before the first broken one?

Comment: @Normadize Not sure. That depends on which blobs are missing. What I would do. `1) Make a copy of the repo. (Even if repo is currently corrupted, it is easy to mess it up even more while trying to fix it)`. `2. Try to delete all commits objects which refer to missing blobs.` (This could be quite tedious and time consuming) (This answer to other question might be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/223890/151344 )

Comment: And yes... One "old" commit with missing blobs will break all subsequent commits.

Comment: Well it turns out there are only 4 dangling commits, and all of them have missing objects - if I interpreted the outputs correctly. I created branches from each of them by using `git branch blah <dangling commit hash>` and then tried to see the log of the new branch by `git log blah` and it does list a bunch of commits (and i can see all the comments) but afte ra few of them it says "error: Could not read <hash>
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit <hash>". So I guess that's that. many thanks both for the help.