# Result of 'git hash-object' for a file different when using core.autocrlf=true?

Tags: git, object, hash, blob, line-endings

I am using `git log --find-object` to [identify commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48590251) by providing git file blobs (file content hashes).

This works fine, I get the blob before for a file by using `git hash-object`

However, when I issue `git hash-object` for the very same file, **and I have set** `core.autocrlf=true`, I get a different blob (hash value).

Accordingly `git log --find-object` does not identify a commit that corresponds to that 'new' blob.

What happens here? Does this mean that `git hash-object` does not 'work' when `core.autocrlf=true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing a file to the database, the `core.autocrlf` tells `git` to run a filter on all input files to convert CRLF line endings to LF. It has to do this before calculating the hash of the blob, because every byte you change affects the hash, by definition.

Since `git hash-object` is the plumbing command used to do this, it too has to perform these filters. If you want to suppress that, and find the hash of the file if no filters were run, you can use the `--no-filters` option. [Manual summary](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object):

> --no-filters
>
> Hash the contents as is, ignoring any input filter that would have been chosen by the attributes mechanism, including the end-of-line conversion. If the file is read from standard input then this is always implied, unless the --path option is given.

Comment: Ah, well, it is all in the man pages... I should have been able to look that up myself! Thanks!